# Entendendo o modo pythônico de lidar com propriedades

Tags: python, python-3.x, getters-setters, propriedade, decorator-pattern

Eu estou a tempo procurando entender como funciona essa questão de propriedades em python. Mas o problema é que em todos os tutoriais net à fora só encontro o maldito exemplo com apenas um atributo. Estou procurando um exemplo onde que tenha mais haver com o dia a dia. Tipo com mais atributos como nome, idade, telefone, acesso (boolean), etc.. Tenho dúvidas como por exemplo, deve-se criar um @property, @setter para cada atributo?
Como ficaria o exemplo abaixo se tivéssemos os dados de uma pessoa como nome, telefone, idade, email, etc....

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._name = ''

    @property
    def name(self):
        print "Getting: %s" % self._name
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        print "Setting: %s" % value
        self._name = value.title()

    @name.deleter
    def name(self):
        print ">Deleting: %s" % self._name
        del self._name
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você declara o *getter*, o método pode ser usado em seguida para marcar o `setter` e o `deleter` (eu omiti o `deleter` do meu exemplo para ficar mais curto).

```
class Pessoa(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._nome = None
        self._idade = None
        self._telefone = None

    @property
    def nome(self):
        print "Getting: %s" % self._nome
        return self._nome

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, value):
        print "Setting: %s" % value
        self._nome = value

    @property
    def idade(self):
        print "Getting: %s" % self._idade
        return self._idade

    @idade.setter
    def idade(self, value):
        print "Setting: %s" % value
        self._idade = value

    @property
    def telefone(self):
        print "Getting: %s" % self._telefone
        return self._telefone

    @telefone.setter
    def telefone(self, value):
        print "Setting: %s" % value
        self._telefone = value
```

Comment: Exatamente como eu imaginava. Eu estava resistente em aceitar que fosse dessa forma. Pois eu havia assistido um vídeo do Luciano Ramalho onde ele "tacava o pau" criticando os gets e sets do java.
Mas ta me parecendo que no final dá no mesmo.

Comment: @DevelSilva eu não estou necessariamente recomendando que você use properties sem necessidade. Você só perguntou qual era a sintaxe. Eu definitivamente não recomendo usá-las só por usar. Elas têm seu valor mas também podem ser usadas abusivamente.

Comment: qual seria um caso realmente necessário? Por exemplo em entidades comuns, Pessoa, Cliente, Carro, etc. O que usar para esses casos? gets e sets comuns, padrão java?

Comment: Se você está simplesmente setando e lendo de um campo privado, eu considero o uso de propriedades desnecessário. Por outro lado, se você quer criar uma propriedade _read-only_ (ou _write-only_), ou se você deseja validar o valor passado, ou criar uma propriedade calculada/derivada de outras, então esse uso faz mais sentido.

Comment: Um exemplo, em uma classe `Pessoa` use campos simples para todos os atributos, como `nome` e `data_de_nascimento`, e use uma propriedade `idade` que é derivada da `data_de_nascimento`