# O que é código pythônico?

Tags: python, terminologia

Em programação Python é comum ouvir o termo pythônico (ou *pythonic*), veja:

- [SOpt: "Entendendo o modo pythônico de lidar com propriedades"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72143/entendendo-o-modo-pyth%C3%B4nico-de-lidar-com-propriedades)
- [SOpt: "Passar parâmetros de forma pythônica"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112076/passar-par%C3%A2metros-de-forma-pyth%C3%B4nica)
- [Wikipedia: "Python (programming language)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language))
- [python.net: "Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic  Python"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)

O que significa o termo pythônico e o que diferencia um código não-pythônico de um código pythônico?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/41056

Answer (score 97, accepted):

### O que é Pythonico?

A expressão *pythonico*, originada no inglês, *pythonic*, é uma expressão vaga, isto é, sem um significado exato. Geralmente é utilizada para referenciar um código [idiomático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/5878) em Python. O termo ficou famoso e mundialmente utilizado principalmente pelo sucesso que o Python faz com algumas soluções extremamente simples. Já cheguei a ouvir citações dizendo: "se você não fez em uma linha de código, você fez errado". Claro que isso não é literal, mas expressa bem como é a abordagem da linguagem.

### O que faz um código ser considerado *pythonico*?

Criado com Tim Peters, um *BDFL* da linguagem Python, e extremamente bem recebido pela comunidade, o grupo de 20 aforismos conhecido como [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (PEP 20) é o ponto principal para definir se um código é idomático ou não. Definido pelo próprio Guido van Rossum, criador da linguagem, como a perfeita descrição da filosofia do Python, basta fazer um código consistente com todos os aforismos para ter um código idiomático. São eles:

(1) [*Beautiful is better than ugly.*](https://zen-of-python.info/beautiful-is-better-than-ugly.html#1)

Bonito é melhor que feio.

(2) [*Explicit is better than implicit.*](https://zen-of-python.info/explicit-is-better-than-implicit.html#2)

Explícito é melhor que implícito.

(3) [*Simple is better than complex.*](https://zen-of-python.info/simple-is-better-than-complex.html#3)

Simples é melhor que complexo.

(4) [*Complex is better than complicated.*](https://zen-of-python.info/complex-is-better-than-complicated.html#4)

Complexo é melhor que complicado.

(5) [*Flat is better than nested.*](https://zen-of-python.info/flat-is-better-than-nested.html#5)

Plano é melhor do que aninhado.

(6) [*Sparse is better than dense.*](https://zen-of-python.info/sparse-is-better-than-dense.html#6)

Esparso é melhor que denso.

(7) [*Readability counts.*](https://zen-of-python.info/readability-counts.html#7)

Legibilidade conta.

(8) [*Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.*](https://zen-of-python.info/special-cases-arent-special-enough-to-break-the-rules.html#8)

Casos especiais não são especiais o bastante para quebrar as regras.

(9) [*Although practicality beats purity.*](https://zen-of-python.info/although-practicality-beats-purity.html#9)

Ainda que praticidade vença a pureza.

(10) [*Errors should never pass silently.*](https://zen-of-python.info/errors-should-never-pass-silently.html#10)

Erros nunca devem passar silenciosamente.

(11) [*Unless explicitly silenced.*](https://zen-of-python.info/unless-explicitly-silenced.html#11)

A menos que sejam explicitamente silenciados - vide aforismo 2.

(12) [*In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.*](https://zen-of-python.info/in-the-face-of-ambiguity-refuse-the-temptation-to-guess.html#12)

Diante da ambiguidade, recuse a tentação de adivinhar.

(13) [*There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.*](https://zen-of-python.info/there-should-be-one-and-preferably-only-one-obvious-way-to-do-it.html#13)

Deveria haver um — e preferencialmente só um — modo óbvio para fazer algo: o modo *pythonico*.

(14) [*Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.*](https://zen-of-python.info/although-that-way-may-not-be-obvious-at-first-unless-youre-dutch.html#14)

Embora esse modo possa não ser óbvio a princípio a menos que você seja holandês.

(15) [*Now is better than never.*](https://zen-of-python.info/now-is-better-than-never.html#15)

Agora é melhor que nunca.

(16) [*Although never is often better than right now.*](https://zen-of-python.info/although-never-is-often-better-than-right-now.html#16)

Embora nunca frequentemente seja melhor que agora.

(17) [*If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.*](https://zen-of-python.info/if-the-implementation-is-hard-to-explain-its-a-bad-idea.html#17)

Se a implementação é difícil de explicar, é uma má ideia.

(18) [*If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.*](https://zen-of-python.info/if-the-implementation-is-easy-to-explain-it-may-be-a-good-idea.html#18)

Se a implementação é fácil de explicar, pode ser uma boa ideia - mas não necessariamente.

(19) [*Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!*](https://zen-of-python.info/namespaces-are-one-honking-great-idea--lets-do-more-of-those.html#19)

Namespaces são uma grande ideia — vamos ter mais dessas!

[image]

Se reparar, o aforismo 7 indica que legibilidade do código é algo importante. De fato, é, tanto que um dos principais itens levados em conta pelo Guido van Rossum ao criar a linguagem foi que o código devesse ser legível aos humanos na mesma facilidade que uma máquina conseguisse lê-lo. Isto é, as estruturas deveriam seguir uma organização que se aproximassem ao máximo da escrita cotidiana do desenvolvedor, utilizando os blocos de indentação para gerenciar contextos. A formatação do código é tão importante no Python que a principal [Python Enhancement Proposals (PEP)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/) é a que define o guia de estilos para códigos Python: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). E ninguém mais indicado que o próprio criador da linguagem para definir o que é melhor para ela, certo? O documento é relativamente longo e inviável transcrevê-lo aqui, mas isso não deve reduzir sua importância. Para facilitar, você pode instalar em seu editor algum componente relacionado ao *Python Lint* que provavelmente ele te guiará conforme todas as recomendações da PEP 8.

### Exemplos

Segue abaixo uma lista de exemplos simples que são considerados e aceitos pela comunidade como pythonicos.

1. #### Permutar valores em variáveis

   Outras linguagens:

   ```
   int x = 1,
       y = 2,
       temp;

   temp = x;
   x = y;
   y = temp;
   ```

   Em Python:

   ```
   x = 1
   y = 2

   x, y = y, x
   ```

   O código funciona pois o que na verdade ocorre é um tratamento de tuplas. A sintaxe do lado direito, `y, x`, gera uma tupla de dois valores (*tuple packing*). Já a sintaxe do lado esquerdo faz o oposto (*tuple unpacking*), atribuindo cada posição da tupla à uma variável, fazendo com que `x` receba o valor de `y` e `y` o valor de `x`.
2. #### Declaração de `switch`?

   Outras linguagens:

   ```
   int num = 3;

   switch (num) {
       case 0:
           ...
       case 1:
           ...
       case 2:
           ...
       default:
           ...
   }
   ```

   Não existe uma construção `switch` no Python. O modo pythônico de fazer é usando um dicionário.

   ```
   opcoes = { 
       1: uma_funcao_qualquer,
       2: outra_funcao_qualquer,
       3: mais_uma_funcao
   }
   ```

   E chamar a função assim:

   ```
   opcoes[variavel_inteira]()
   ```

   Desta forma, `opcoes[variavel_inteira]` retornará a respectiva função e será executada imediatamente devido aos `()` no final da linha.
3. #### Declaração de `do .. while`?

   Para a validação de um valor de entrada do usuário, por exemplo, é comum que tenhamos que ficar pedindo um novo valor até que o mesmo seja válido. Em outras linguagens há a estrutura `do..while`, mas em Python não. Veja o exemplo para a leitura de um valor natural:

   Outras linguagens:

   ```
   int num;

   do {
       scanf("%d", &num);
   } while (num < 0);
   ```

   Python:

   ```
   while True:
       num = int(input())
       if num >= 0:
           break;
   ```

   Ou seja, em Python cria-se um loop infinito com `while True` e internamente é verificado se a condição desejada foi satisfeita, encerrando o loop com `break`.
4. #### Percorrendo uma lista com chave/valor:

   É bastante comum que tenhamos que percorrer uma lista de valores utilizando tanto a chave quando o valor desta lista. Algumas linguagens fornecem a estrutura `foreach` que retorna o par chave/valor, porém no Python, a estrutura `for` retorna apenas o valor.

   Outras linguagens:

   ```
   int seq[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       printf("%d, %d\n", i, seq[i]);
   }
   ```

   Python:

   ```
   seq = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

   for key, value in enumerate(seq):
       print(key, value)
   ```

   O acesso ao par chave/valor é feito através da função [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), que retorna uma tupla de dois valores: o primeiro a chave e o segundo o valor. Dentro da estrutura do `for` é feito uma *tuple unpacking* para as variáveis `key` e `value`.
5. #### Testando Vazio/Nulo:

Em Python, toda e qualquer variável testada como booleano devolve `False` nos seguintes casos:

- `False`
- `None`
- `0`, seja qual for o tipo numérico
- Sequências vazias (`''`, `()`, `[]`)
- Mapeamentos vazios: `{}`
- Instâncias de classes "vazias", cujas classes implementem ou `__nonzero__()` (e devolvam `False`) ou `__len__()` (e devolvam zero).

Isso é útil para testar sequências com valores vazios, falsos ou zerados:

```
for item in lista:
    if item: print(item)
```

6. #### Percorrer linhas de um arquivo

   Python:

   ```
   with open("/tmp/arquivo.txt") as file:
       for line in file:
           print(line) # line possui o conteúdo de cada linha
   ```

   Para mais detalhes do `with`, leia [Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878). A função nativa [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) retorna um *generator* que iterará sobre o arquivo, desta forma é possível utilizar o objeto diretamente em um laço de repetição, sem ter que armazenar o conteúdo inteiro do arquivo em memória.

### Referências e leituras obrigatórias

[1] The Zen of Python: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

[2] Style Guide for Python Code: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, Anderson. Só acrescentar que o texto "The Zen of Python" também é uma PEP (Python Enhancement Proposal), é a PEP 20.

Comment: Eu costumo usar `if`/`elif`/`else` no lugar do switch.

Answer (score 37):

A maneira "tradicional" - se é que eu posso chamar assim - de escrever um código da maneira que conhecemos pode ser simplificado usando Python, quando você olha a estrutura de um loop construído em Java ou C:

Em C por exemplo:

```
//aloca 1000 posições
int vetor[1000]; 

for( int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
    vetor[i] = i;
}
```

É um `for` tradicional que preenche as 1000 posições do vetor conforme vai incrementando até o final. Esse código pode ser escrito em Python, certo?

Seguindo a mesma estrutura do C, em Python:

```
#aloca 1000 posições
vetor= [None] * 1000

for i in range(1000):
    vetor[i]=i
```

A grosso modo, Python é conhecido por ser uma linguagem de rápido desenvolvimento, como dizemos por aí: "rápido e rasteiro" quando você faz um `for` em Python da maneira que te mostrei, não está errado, ele funciona, mas não é considerado uma maneira *pythônica*, você esta desperdiçando as vantagens que a linguagem te dá. Você pode fazer isso de outra maneira, mais simples, mais rápido, mais prático, mais organizado, etc...
Veja o que é considerado uma maneira *pythônica* de fazer o mesmo `for`:

```
vetor = [i for i in range(1000)]
```

> O que diferencia um código *não-pythônico* de um código dito *pythônico*?

Tá ai um exemplo prático, você aproveitou os artifícios da linguagem para fazer a mesma coisa em uma só linha, você está usando as vantagens da linguagem no seu código, se você olhar no wiki do [Python](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python), veja as prioridades da linguagem:

> Prioriza a legibilidade do código sobre a velocidade ou
> expressividade. Combina uma sintaxe concisa e clara.

Tá aí uma explicação menos teórica e mais prática :-)

Comment: Ótima explicação também, com um exemplo prático.

Comment: eu faria `vetor = list(range(1000))`

Comment: @JJoao a intenção não foi mostrar como criar um vetor de 0 até 1000, a intenção foi demonstrar como fazer um for(loop) de maneira Pythônica  ....

Comment: @ederwander, eu sei, eu sei. A tua resposta está optima (+1). Eu só comentava porque implicitamente à noção "pytónica" para mim há associada algo de comparativo, e de "não há uma solução mais pythónica que" :-)

Answer (score 23):

As expressões idiomáticas de uma linguagem de programação são definidas por seus usuários. A comunidade Python concebeu e vem utilizando o adjetivo *pythônico* para descrever qualquer código que siga um estilo em particular. Os desenvolvedores Python preferem ser explícitos, escolhem o simples em vez do complicado e maximizam a legibilidade.

Quando você vem de outra linguagem de programação para o Python, querendo ou não, você vem com o *sotaque* das outras que aprendera, e passa a escrever seu código em Python como se fosse nelas.

Siga o Guia do Estilo PEP 8, que é o guia de estilo para formatar o código em Python. Você pode escrever o código em Python da maneira que bem entender, desde que a sintaxe seja válida. Contudo empregar um estilo consistente deixa seu código mais fácil de ler e distribuir.

Answer (score 15):

*Pythonico* significa *idiomático*.

*Código idiomático* é aquele que é escrito usando as estruturas e convenções mais comuns de uma determinada linguagem.

Exemplo:

A maioria dos programadores Python escreve:

```
for elemento in minha_lista:
    #faca alguma coisa
```

Ao inves de:

```
   for i in range(0, len(minha_lista)):
       #faca alguma coisa
```

A idea de escrever código idiomatico é que as pessoas vão entender o seu trabalho mais facilmente.

Não existe uma pessoa ou entidade que define 100% o que é Python idiomatico, mas boa parte da maneira que as pessoas escrevem Python vem da:

- [Documentação Ofical](https://docs.python.org/3/)
- [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (Guia de Estilo Python)