# Soma de elementos em listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[[3, 2, 7], [8, -2, 5], [-1, 4, 3], [2, 2, -9]]
```

De seguida guarda em três variáveis distintas, ignorando os valores negativos, a soma dos elementos separadamente. Ou seja, a soma do primeiro elemento de cada sublista, a soma do segundo elemento de cada sublista e a
soma do terceiro elemento de cada sublista. Depois cria um dicionário com a correspondência de chave/valor dos números de 1 a 15, por exemplo:

```
{1:"Um", 2:"Dois" … 15:"Quinze"}.
```

Para finalizar, fazendo corresponder o valor do resultado à chave do dicionário, apresenta o resultado individualmente em forma de texto.

Comecei com este código. A minha primeira questão é faço um ciclo `for if else`? Como consigo que some apenas os positivos? Como chamo os blocos? da mesma forma que nas listas 0,1,2,3?

```
lista=[[3,2,7], [8,-2,5], [-1,4,3], [2,2,-9]]

var1=""
var2=""
var3=""

for int in range(len(lista))
    if (int in lista)
    var1=
```

Comment: [Nessa página](http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-listas-em-python/37460) tem um tutorial breve sobre listas, pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considere a lista de entrada:

```py
values = [[3, 2, 7], [8, -2, 5], [-1, 4, 3], [2, 2, -9]]
```

Desejando somar os valores de cada lista em um determinado índice, devemos, então redefinir a lista conforme nossa necessidade. Para tal, utilizamos a função nativa [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
values = list(zip(*values))
```

> **Nota:** Utilizar o `*` faz com que cada posição da lista seja passada como parâmetro à função. Fazer `zip(*values)` é o equivalente à `zip(values[0], values[1], values[2])`, mas com menos código e muito mais fácil de ler.

Desta forma, nossa lista será da seguinte forma:

```py
[(3, 8, -1, 2), (2, -2, 4, 2), (7, 5, 3, -9)]
```

Ou seja, criou-se uma tupla com os valores no índice 0 de cada lista, outra com os valores do índice 1 e outra com os valores no índice 2. Basta agora somarmos os valores quando os mesmos não forem negativos, armazenando o resultado em variáveis, utilizando a função nativa [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum).

```
sum_1 = sum(i for i in values[0] if i >= 0) # Resulta: 13
sum_2 = sum(i for i in values[1] if i >= 0) # Resulta: 8
sum_3 = sum(i for i in values[2] if i >= 0) # Resulta: 15
```

É pedido, também, para que seja definido um dicionário com os números por extenso. Assim:

```py
texts = {
  1: "um",
  2: "dois",
  3: "três",
  4: "quatro",
  5: "cinco",
  6: "seis",
  7: "sete",
  8: "oito",
  9: "nove",
  10: "dez",
  11: "onze",
  12: "doze",
  13: "treze",
  14: "catorze",
  15: "quinze",
}
```

Finalmente, é apresentado o resultado:

```py
print("A soma 1 resultou em: {}".format(texts[sum_1]))
print("A soma 2 resultou em: {}".format(texts[sum_2]))
print("A soma 3 resultou em: {}".format(texts[sum_3]))
```

Que será:

```
A soma 1 resultou em: treze
A soma 2 resultou em: oito
A soma 3 resultou em: quinze
```

Veja o código funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HEyQ/0) ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/UeJEDX).

Comment: O problema de se usar um dicionario assim e que se a soma resultar em um numero que não esteja em um dicionario o programa informaria um erro, dessa forma teria que utilizar tratamento de erro e mesmo assim não se obteria um resultado esperado. Outro ponto e que salvar os resultados em variáveis pode resultar em novos erros  caso a matriz seja maior.

Comment: @Arcashaid, de fato, mas o enunciado pede explicitamente desta maneira e, considerando uma solução de exercício, TODOS os requisitos levantados pelo enunciado devem ser satisfeitos.

Comment: O problema e que o enunciado não especifica o tamanho de colunas

Comment: Serão sempre três valores em cada sub-lista, está claro isso em: *a soma do primeiro elemento de cada sublista, a soma do segundo elemento de cada sublista e a soma do terceiro elemento de cada sublista*.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa encarar o problema como uma matriz
(que é acessada: `matriz[posicao_i][posicao_j]`))

`1.` Deixe fixada a coluna e percorra todas as linhas, fazendo então as sua condições e operações;
`2.` incremente a posição da coluna;
`3.` repita.

```
# para somar ignorando os valores negativos:

lista = [[3,2,7], [8,-2,5], [-1,4,3], [2,2,-9]]

valores = []

for coluna in range(len(lista[0])):
    soma = 0

    for linha in range(len(lista)):
        if(lista[linha][coluna] >= 0):
            soma += lista[linha][coluna]

    valores.append(soma)

print(valores)
```

Comment: Obrigado agora so tenho de armazenar o resultado em variáveis diferentes.

Comment: Por mais que possa resolver o problema, está solução não é considerada boa em Python. Faça melhor uso das ferramentas da linguagem e terá resultados muito mais interessantes. Busque sempre analisar qual é a solução mais [*pythonica*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-um-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico).