# Desenhar um retângulo utilizando estruturas de repetições em Python

Tags: python

Tenho que resolver a seguinte atividade em Python:

Preciso escrever um programa que imprima um retângulo com as bordas completas e o meio aberto:

```
>>> digite a largura: 10
>>> digite a altura: 3
##########
#        #
##########
```

Mas o meu programa está fazendo assim:

```
>>> digite a largura: 10
>>> digite a altura: 3
#        #
#        #
##########
```

Como corrigir?

Meu código:

```
linha = int(input("digite a largura:"))
altura = int(input("digite a altura:"))

while  altura > 0:
   print("#", end = "")
   coluna = 2
   while coluna < linha: 
    if altura == 1 or coluna == linha:
        print("#",end="")
    else:
        print(end = " ")
    coluna = coluna + 1
   print("#")
   altura = altura - 1
```

Comment: Sendo Python, procure soluções [pythonicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878). **Dica**: Fazer `'#' * 10` retorna a *string* `##########` e fazer `'#' + '_' * 8 + '#'`retorna `#________#` (substitui o espaço em branco por `_` por causa da formatação aqui do comentário). Isso diminuiria em muito a complexidade do seu programa.

Comment: Compreendo...Mas, eu precisa automatizar para qualquer largura e altura.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solução alternativa

Como comentado, uma solução mais simples é utilizar a multiplicação de *strings* no Python:

```py
# Lê o tamanho do retângulo:
largura = int(input("digite a largura:"))
altura = int(input("digite a altura:"))

# Imprime a borda superior:
print('#' * largura)

# Imprime bordas laterais:
for _ in range(altura-2):
    print('#' + ' ' * (largura-2) + '#')

# Imprime borda inferior:
print('#' * largura)
```

Rodando o programa:

```
>>> digite a largura: 10
>>> digite a altura: 5
##########
#        #
#        #
#        #
##########
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HSuR).

### Sua solução

Analisei seu código e o problema principal é que você altera o valor de `altura` para percorrer as linhas. Isso deixa sua lógica bem mais complexa do que precisa ser, pois o programa não saberá qual é a altura original do retângulo. Para contornar isso, controle a linha a ser exibida com outra variável.

```
# Aqui substitui de linha para largura:
largura = int(input("digite a largura:"))
altura = int(input("digite a altura:"))

# Defini a variável linha para controlar a linha a ser exibida
linha = 1

# Enquanto houver linha a ser exibida:
while  linha <= altura:

    print("#", end = "")
    coluna = 2

    # Substituído linha por largura também
    while coluna < largura: 

        # Se for a primeira linha, a última ou a última coluna
        if linha == 1 or linha == altura or coluna == largura:
            print("#",end="")
        else:
            print(end = " ")

        coluna = coluna + 1

    print("#")

    # Incrementa a variável linha ao invés de decrementar altura
    linha = linha + 1
```

Perceba que, assim, a variável `altura` permanece inalterada e, portanto, sua referência original não é perdida. Rodando o programa:

```
>>> digite a largura: 10
>>> digite a altura: 5
##########
#        #
#        #
#        #
##########
```

Tem-se a saída esperada.

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HSvE/0).

Comment: Estou analisando o seu código, vendo onde está o erro de lógica. Edito a resposta acrescentando isso assim que possível.

Comment: Muito Obrigado... Eu não tinha entendido a multiplicação de  _strings_ Muito interessante essa opção.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius editei a resposta com comentários sobre o seu código. Veja se fui suficientemente claro.

Comment: Ficou totalmente Claro... Compreendi o problema lógico.

Answer (score 1):

Seja `a`=altura e `w`=largura:

```
print(w*"#" + "\n"                                        #####
    + (a-2)*("#" + (w-2)*" " + "#\n")                     #   #   
    + w*"#")                                              #####
```

Answer (score 0):

```
larg = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
alt = int(input("Digite a altura: "))

i=1
while i <=alt:
    if i==1 or i==alt:
        print(larg*"#")
        i+=1
    elif larg== alt:
         #print(larg*"#")
         print( *"#",(larg-3)*" ","#")
         i+=1


    else: 
        print( "#",(larg-(alt+1))*" ","#")
        i+=1
```

Comment: A linha `i += 1` pode ir fora do `if`, sem repeti-la; não tem porque fazer `1*"#"`, nem definir `end = '\n'` que é o valor padrão desse parâmetro.

Comment: Porquê a negativação? O código funciona!  Por favor deixem um comentário

Comment: Também tem o fato de não explicar o que foi feito; e o fato de não gerar a saída desejada (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls5bH.png);

Comment: @Woss consegue me ajudar a corrigi-la? Eu tentei ajudar! funcionou com 4x4, 2x2 e 10x3 mas realmente fui ver aqui e falhou com 10x10....

Comment: Eu submeti esta solução no coursera e aceitaram...