# função recursiva em python para calcular soma dos elementos de uma lista

Tags: python, recursão

Estou com dificuldade em um exercício cujo devo mostrar a soma de todos os elementos de uma lista de forma recursiva.

O código que cheguei só possui a base da recursão, o a recursão em si não fiz, pois não entendi como ela poderia ser aplicada a alguma lista.

Deixarei o código aqui para analisarem:

```
def soma_lista(lista):
if len(lista) == 1:
    return lista[0]
else:
    for i in range (len(lista)):
        soma = lista[i] + soma_lista(lista[i + 1])
    return soma
```

OBS: como disse, não sei como aplicar a parte da recursão; portanto tentei algo aleatório. Ignorem o bloco de código do  else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A recursão, neste caso, faria o papel do laço de repetição, então não precisa utilizar ambos. A sua condição de parada da recursividade está correta: se a lista possuir apenas um elemento, retorne-o. Já no `else`, no lugar do laço, você deverá retornar apenas o primeiro elemento somado com o retorno da função para o resto da lista:

```
return lista[0] + soma_lista(lista[1:])
```

Onde `lista[1:]` retorna a lista a partir do primeiro elemento. Ou seja, a soma de uma lista será igual ao primeiro elemento somado com o resultado da soma do resto da lista e, assim, é feito a recursão:

```
def soma_lista(lista):
    if len(lista) == 1:
        return lista[0]
    else:
        return lista[0] + soma_lista(lista[1:])
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/nf49xz).

Comment: hm, faz sentido. Achava que a recursão só viria para retornar os resultados finais (lista[-1]), nunca imaginaria que ela poderia funcionar como o loop

Answer (score 0):

A recursão é a tecnica onde um método ou função chama a si proprio para chegar ao resultado.

Implementei este de forma Pythônica:

```
def soma_lista(lista=list()):
    '''
    Calcula a somatória dos elementos de uma lista.

    :param lista: lista de elementos inteiros
    :return: int
    >>> soma_lista([1,2,3])
    6
    >>> soma_lista([1,2,3,4])
    10
    >>> soma_lista([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    21
    '''
    try:
        return lista.pop() + soma_lista(lista)
    except IndexError:
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
    print()
```

E este de forma convencional:

```
def soma_lista(lista=list()):
    '''

    :param lista:
    :return:
    >>> soma_lista([1,2,3])
    6
    >>> soma_lista([1,2,3,4])
    10
    >>> soma_lista([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    21
    '''
    if len(lista) >= 1:
        return lista.pop() + soma_lista(lista)
    else:
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
    print()
```

Comment: Pode explicar porquê utilizar a exceção seria a forma pythonica? Eu sinceramente não consigo ver motivos para tal. Aliás, dizer que é pythonica uma solução que faz a soma de elementos de uma lista com recursão já não faz sentido algum.

Comment: A premissa do Modo Pythônico diz que é melhor pedir perdão que permissão. Então em vez de verificar se há um elemento na lista antes de executar, simplesmente executa. E se ocorrer alguma exceção, trate-a.

E neste caso será quando não houver mais elementos na lista. Que são retirados durante a execução do metodo pop().

Comment: Pode me indicar a fonte desta premissa?

Comment: EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) - "melhor pedir perdão do que permissão", disponível em https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html.
Aqui também:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901886/why-is-it-easier-to-ask-forgiveness-than-it-is-to-get-permission-in-python

Comment: Nas palavras de [Guido van Rossun](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-March/133118.html): "*and I disagree with the position that EAFP is better than LBYL, or "generally recommended" by Python.*". Mesmo assim, se quiser comentar algo sobre isso no [O que é um código “pythônico”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878)

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma que considero ser bem didática para mostrar os "mistérios" da recursão nesse caso:

```
def recl(l, i=0):
    try:
        elmnt = l[i]
        i+=1
        return elmnt + recl(l,i)     
    except:
        return 0

print (recl([1,2]))   
3
```

[Execute o codigo no repl.it.](https://repl.it/J5fm/3)