# Como melhorar o meu código?

Tags: python

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import sys

def processar():
    print("Processando...")
    sleep(3)
    print()

def voltar():
    print("1 - Voltar ao inicio")
    print("2 - Sair")
    while True:
        opcao = int(input("> "))
        if (opcao == 1):
            jogo()
        elif (opcao == 2):
            break
        else:
            print("Opcao invalida!")

def jogo():

    computador = randint(0, 5)

    jogador = int(input("Tente adivinhar o número no qual eu pensei (de 0 à 5): "))
    processar()

    while jogador < 0 or jogador > 5:
        jogador = int(input("Opa! Você só pode digitar números de 0 até 2. Tente novamente: "))
        processar()

    if computador == jogador:
            print("Você acertou!!! O número que pensei é: {}".format(computador))
            voltar()
    else:
        print("Você errou. Eu pensei no número {} e você digitou o: {}" .format(computador, jogador))
        voltar()
jogo()
voltar()
```

Comment: O Python é um linguagem bem interessante, existem muitas formas de fazer uma única coisa, daí saiu um termo exclusivo do Python que é o pythonic code, para representar o código idiomático. Dá uma olhada nessa pergunta:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-um-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico

Comment: Qual problema está tentando resolver? O que exatamente você quer melhorar?

Comment: Qual é a finalidade do `processar()`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Acho que a sua função `processar()` não serve para nada. Vou tirar ela.
2. As suas variáveis `computador` e `jogador` são na verdade o número inventado pelo computador e a tentativa do jogador. Sugiro chamá-las de `escolhido` e `tentativa`.
3. A sua mensagem "`Você só pode digitar números de 0 até 2.`" na verdade era para ser de 0 a 5.
4. A sua função `jogo()` chama `voltar()` que chama `jogo()`. Isso não vai dar certo e cria uma recursão complicada. O resultado é que a escolha da opção `sair()` nem sempre saia. O seu programa vai ficar bem confuso com isso. A solução é primeiramente transformar `voltar()` em uma função `menu()` e nunca chamar `menu()` ou `jogo()` de dentro da função `jogo()`.
5. O `if` e o `else` da função `jogo()` estão com níveis de identação diferentes entre si.

Arrumando-se tudo isso, o seu código fica então assim:

```
from random import randint
import sys

def menu():
    jogo()
    while True:
        print("1 - Voltar ao inicio")
        print("2 - Sair")
        opcao = int(input("> "))
        if (opcao == 1):
            jogo()
        elif (opcao == 2):
            break
        else:
            print("Opcao invalida!")

def jogo():
    escolhido = randint(0, 5)
    tentativa = int(input("Tente adivinhar o número no qual eu pensei (de 0 à 5): "))

    while tentativa < 0 or tentativa > 5:
        jogador = int(input("Opa! Você só pode digitar números de 0 até 5. Tente novamente: "))

    if escolhido == tentativa:
        print("Você acertou!!! O número que pensei é: {}".format(escolhido))
    else:
        print("Você errou. Eu pensei no número {} e você digitou o: {}" .format(escolhido, tentativa))

menu()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Eu ainda estou um pouco perdido em relação a chamada de funções. Faltou tbm um pouco de informação e tratamento de exceções.