# Associar duas listas em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Associar duas listas, uma lista com nome de carro e outra lista de cores e cada uma contendo n elementos:

```
listaCarros = ["gol","uno","corsa","palio","idea"]
listaCores = ["branco","verde","preto","cinza","azul"]
```

com a saída neste formato:

"O gol é branco"

eu fiz o seguinte:

```
n=0

while n <= 5:

    print("\nO", end=' ')
    print(listaCarros[n],end=' é ')
    print(listaCores[n])
    n = n + 1
```

deu certo, porém apareceu essa mensagem:

O Traceback (most recent call last): "caminho do arquivo"
line 286, in 
    print(listaCarros[n],end=' é ')
IndexError: list index out of range

teria um jeito melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: @Miguel é bem simples.... Serie  listaCarros = ["gol","corsa","palio"]  e outra de cores do mesmo jeito. E no caso associar as duas só para imprimir naquele formato, deu certo aquele jeito que fiz, porém está dando essa msg de IndexError e se por acaso tem algum jeito melhor pra fazer isso

Comment: Estou a constriur uma resposta William

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A condição `<= 5` está errada, pois se as listas têm 5 elementos só têm entre 0 e 4 indices (pois estes começam em 0), experimenta nessa versão do código `while n < 5`, ou melhor, `while n < len(listaCarros):` .

Dito isto, aqui fica uma versão mais [pythonica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-um-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico/192347#192347) e com menos linhas, o 'jeito melhor':

```
listaCores = ['azul', 'vermelho', 'verde', 'laranja', 'branco', 'preto']
listaCarros = ['mazda', 'toyota', 'honda', 'pegeot', 'mercedez', 'BMW']
text = ''
for carro, cor in zip(listaCarros, listaCores):
    text += '\nO {} é {}'.format(carro, cor)
print(text)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/L6EB)

Para fazer como estavas a fazer (com while) usando este exemplo (precisas de ter o cuidado de as listas pussuírem o mesmo número de elementos, ou construir o ciclo com base na lista com menos elementos):

```
listaCores = ['azul', 'vermelho', 'verde', 'laranja', 'branco', 'preto']
listaCarros = ['mazda', 'toyota', 'honda', 'pegeot', 'mercedez', 'BMW', 'saf', 'safs']

n = 0
text = ''
min_list = min(len(listaCores), len(listaCarros))
while n < min_list: # fazes isto caso nao tenhas a certeza que as listas tem o mesmo num de elementos
    text += '\nO {} é {}'.format(listaCarros[n], listaCores[n])
    n += 1
print(text)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/L6Ek)

Comment: isso mesmo...  legal... é porque estou iniciando agora no python e por exemplo no C, se eu colocar printf("O %s eh %s", arrayCarro[i], arrayCor[i]); e imprimo certinho no padrão...  mas ein python queria ver se tinha outro jeito de formatar essa saida sem ser daquele jeito que fiz... vou testar desse jeito que tu fez!

Comment: entendi mano! muito obrigado.

Comment: De nada @WilliamHenrique , adicionei demonstrações para veres, de ambas as construções