# Operando em uma lista de listas com o condicional

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Estou tentanto usar compreensão de listas em um código mas eu "empaquei" em usar as estruturas for e if em determinada parte. Alguém pode me auxiliar? Basicamente eu tenho uma lista chamada "sup" cujas 2000 entradas são também listas de diversos comprimentos. Tenho uma outra lista de listas chamada "gap" (também com 2000 entradas e cujas listas-elemento são de mesmo comprimento da lista "sup".
Eu devo "apagar" todo elemento em "sup" cujo correspondente em "gap" é igual a 0. (Por exemplo, sup[i][j] deve ser apagado de sup[i] se gap[i][j] é igual a zero para todo i e j). As duas listas "sup" e "gap" possuem entradas do tipo "float" ainda que a "gap" só contenha zeros e uns.

De tudo o que tentei escrever a única escrita que não acusou erro de sintaxe (uso python 3 no Spyder) foi a seguinte mas que também não funciona.

```
    sup_new = [[sup[i].remove(int(j)) for j in gap[i] if gap[i][int(j)] > 0] for i in range(len(sup))]
```

Mas o retorno é

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Alguém pode me mostrar onde estou errando? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

O erro é que você está tentando remover aquilo que não existe. Ao executar, por exemplo, `[1, 2].remove(3)`, dará o erro citado, porque não há como remover o número 3 da lista `[1, 2]`. Você está tentando remover o `int(j)` de `sup[i]`, mas ele não existe. Outro detalhe é que o retorno de `list.remove` é `None`, pois ele **modifica** a própria lista, então ao utilizá-lo dentro da compreensão de listas você estaria criando uma lista somente de `None`, não com as listas filtradas.

Python já possui uma função que filtra uma sequência com base em outra sequência: `itertools.compress`.

```
from itertools import compress

x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = [1.0, 0.0, 1.0]

result = compress(x, y)

print(list(result))  # ['a', 'c']
```

No exemplo acima, `'b'` não é retornado porque em `y` o valor é 0.0.

Assim, basta fazer:

```
sup_new = [list(compress(s, g)) for s, g in zip(sup, gap)]
```

O `list` em `list(compress(...))` serve apenas para forçar que seja uma lista ao invés de um iterador do tipo `itertools.compress`.

Sobre a classe `zip`, leia como [Associar duas listas em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239962/5878)

Comment: Woss, obrigado pela ajuda. Nunca tinha lido sobre essas associações de listas. vou ler à respeito. Obrigado mesmo"

Comment: @LucianoMagrini Adicionei no início da resposta uma descrição do que fez errado também...

Comment: Woss, agradeço novamente. Estou lendo sobre essa associação de listas e essa função zip que não conhecia. Faz todo o sentido a sua descrição do meu erro. Entrei com sua sugestão no meu código mas ele retorna um erro de sintaxe. Veja:

`sup_new = [list(compress(s, g)) for zip(sup, gap)]` cujo retorno é

`File "<ipython-input-335-670598897d6d>", line 1
       sup_new = [list(compress(s, g)) for zip(sup, gap)]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @LucianoMagrini O código foi corrigido na resposta já... estava mesmo errado

Comment: obrigado. Realmente faltavam os loopings rs. Estou há dias quebrando a cabeça com isso. Acho que vou parar tudo o que estou fazendo e vou ler tod a documentação sobre listas primeiro. Retroceder uma casa para ganhar tempo depois. Realmente, valeu!