# Escrever indice de uma lista em outra lista

Tags: python, funções, lista

```
T = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0]
def acoes(T):
    listaAction=[]
    for i in T:
            if(T[i]==0):
                    listaAction.append(T.index(i))

    return listaAction

print(acoes(T))
```

Como faço para escrever os indices da lista T que tem valor 0  em listaAction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aproveitando o que tens podes fazer assim:

```
def acoes(T):
    listaAction=[]
    for idx, i in enumerate(T):
        if(i==0):
            listaAction.append(idx)
    return listaAction

T = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0]
print(acoes(T)) # [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```

`acoes(T)` vai retornar uma lista com os indices em `T` cujo valor é zero

Podes fazer de uma maneira ainda mais [pythonica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-um-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico):

```
def acoes(T):
    return [idx for idx, i in enumerate(T) if i == 0]

T = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0]
print(acoes(T)) # [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MtBM) de ambos os exemplos