# Como somar vários números que foram digitados no output?

Tags: python

O que tenho até agora:

```
for c in range(3):
    n = int(input())
    n += n #tenho quase certeza que essa parte não está certa
print(n)
```

Como somar vários números que foram digitados no *output*?

Comment: Não está somando corretamente.

Comment: A variável que recebe o total deve ser criada fora do loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás a fazer overwrite ao valor de `n` quando fazes `n = int(input())`, faz antes:

```
total = 0
for _ in range(3):
    n = int(input())
    total += n
print(total)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/NMk1)

Ou com menos linhas/variáveis:

```
total = 0
for _ in range(3):
    total += int(input())
print(total)
```

[*Python style*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-um-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico):

```
total = sum(int(input()) for _ in range(3))
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que fez?

Comment: Tu estavas a anular o valor anterior de n quando fazias `n = int(input())`, depois só estavas a somar-lo com ele próprio (equivalente a `n*2`) na linha seguinte

Comment: No trecho `n = int(input())` dentro do loop você declarava a variável novamente e ela perdia o valor da soma anterior `n += n`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte código...

```
valores = list(map(int, input('Digite todos os valores: ').split()))
print(f'\033[32mA soma dos valores digitados é: {sum(valores)}')
```

Veja o funcionamento deste código no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/pgulsabg-solkarped).

Quando executamos este código, recebemos a seguinte mensagem...

```
Digite todos os valores:
```

Neste momento devemos digitar `todos` os valores que desejamos, na `mesma` linha, separados por um `espaço` e, em seguida, pressionar a tecla `enter`.

Se, por exemplo, quisermos digitar os valores `3, 4, 5, 6`, quando o programa solicitar a digitação dos valores, devemos digitar da seguinte forma:

```
3 4 5 6
```

...e posteriormente pressionar enter.

A partir desse momento o programa irá calcular a soma de todos os valores que foram digitados e armazenados na lista `valores`.

Observe também, que este código soma uma quantidade de valores indefinidos e, para encerrar a digitação, basta pressionar `enter`.

Em outras palavras, se você digita `3` valores e pressionar `enter` será somado os 3 valores.

Agora, se você digitar `100` valores e pressionar enter, será somado os 100 valores.