# Dicionário e estrutura de repetição

Tags: python, loop, dicionário

O problema pede para eu contar o tamanho de buracos no texto
exp: A, D, R, O, P tem apenas um buraco, e B possui dois
eu fiz o seguinte código:

```
qnt = int(input())

cont = 0

l = []

for i in range(qnt):

    txt = input()


dic = {'A':1, 'D':1, 'O':1, 'P':1, 'R':1, 'B':2}

for i in txt:

    if dic.get(i, 0):

       cont += dic[i]

print(cont)
```

No entanto, só aparece a quantidade de buracos do ultimo texto, e eu preciso de cada texto.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro vamos entender o porque de estar retornando apenas a quantidade  do ultimo. Considerando o código que aqui está, na linha **5** você tem um lista nomeada de `l`, porém, não faz o uso da mesma em nenhuma outra parte.

Na linha **7** você recupera a entrada do usuário, e não armazena em uma lista, por esse motivo, sempre a ultima entrada será o valor de `txt`.

```
...
5 l = []
6 
7 for i in range(qnt):
8 
9     txt = input()
...
```

Acredito eu que, o que você estava tentando fazer era adicionar o valor de `txt` na lista `l`

```
...
5 l = []
6 
7 for i in range(qnt):
8 
9     txt = input()
10    l.append(txt)
...
```

Caso faça isso, teria que mudar a linha **15**:

```
15 for i in txt:
```

Para:

```
15 for i in l:
```

Mas pode deixar ele mais [Pythônico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192347/60376).

```
dic = {'A':1, 'D':1, 'O':1, 'P':1, 'R':1, 'B':2}
cont = 0
for i in range(int(input())):
  txt = input()
  if txt in dic: cont += dic[txt]

print(cont)
```

> Exemplo funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SnappyDarkslateblueIsabellineshrike).

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que para o problema dado é necessário usar pelo menos dois loop fors encadeados.
No código que você mostra os loop estão separados e a variável text é reescrita sem o valor da sua entra ser somada à variável contador.

```
# Dicionário
dic = {'A': 1, 'D': 1, 'O': 1, 'P': 1, 'R': 1, 'B': 2}

# Solicita ao usuário o número de entradas
num_entradas = int(input("Informe o número de entradas: "))

# Inicializa uma lista vazia para armazenar as entradas
entradas = []

# Loop para coletar as entradas do usuário
for _ in range(num_entradas):
    entrada = input("Digite uma entrada: ").upper()  # Converte a entrada para maiúsculas
    entradas.append(entrada)

# Inicializa uma variável para a soma total
soma_total = 0

# Itera sobre as entradas e atualiza a soma total dos valores das letras
for entrada in entradas:
    for letra in entrada:
        if letra in dic:
            soma_total += dic[letra]

# Exibe a soma total geral
print("Soma total dos valores das letras encontradas:", soma_total)
```