# Revisão de código: Programa que simula o "jogo das portas": ou você ganha um carro ou um bode!

Tags: python, python-3.x, revisão-de-código

Escreva um programa para simular o [jogo das portas](http://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_de_Monty_Hall). Faça um programa que tenha
a saída como a seguinte:

Olá, bem-vindo ao nosso programa! Vamos ver se você vai ganhar um carro ou não!
Escolha uma porta: 3
Você escolheu a porta 3, mas
eu lhe informo que na porta 2 há um bode.
Deseja trocar de porta (1 - Sim/ 0 - Não): 1
Ganhou um carro!

Minha solução:

```
import random #selecionar a porta
testes = int(input("Digite o número de testes: "))
bode =0
trocar =0 #nao trocar

for i in range(testes):
    porta = random.randrange(1,4) #portas de 1 a 3
    premio = random.randint(1,3) #randint inclui o extremo!
    bode = random.randint(1,3)
    if premio != bode and premio !=porta:
        print("A porta {} tem um bode. ".format(bode))

        trocar = int(input("Deseja trocar? "))
        if trocar == 1:
            porta = int(input("Digite a porta: "))


    if porta ==premio:
        print("Ganhou")
        break
    else:
        print("Não ganhou! Que pena!")
```

Nos meus testes o programa está funcionando mas gostaria de uma solução mais pythonica para aprender o estilo!

Comment: Não entendi o downvote. Não vejo nada de errado em pedir uma forma mais pythônica para uma solução já apresentada. Não passa de um code review.

Comment: @Piovezan: concordo! É apenas um code review!

Comment: O que seria solução mais pythonica? Seria algo com menos linha de código?

Comment: Talvez seja necessário dar um editada no título, e colocar Revisão de Código, ser mais claro para que as pessoas de fora possam encontrar a sua pergunta para resolver seu problema.

Comment: @Sveen: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico/192347

Comment: @Sveen , sobre código pythônico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/64969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Formatação

O espaçamento do seu código não está bom. O código está demasiadamente compacto e isso atrapalha a leitura. Além disso, não há um padrão.

Exemplo:

```py
testes = int(input("Digite o número de testes: "))
bode =0
```

Na linha de cima há um espaço após o sinal de atribuição, na linha de baixo, não.

A comunidade Python costuma usar a [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) como um guia para formatar o código. Você deve usar também!

### Comentários no código

Há muitos comentários desnecessários no seu código. Só comente quando o comentário realmente adicionar uma informação valiosa que não fica explícita no próprio código.

### Usabilidade pt 1

Se o usuário digitar um valor não-numérico, seu programa exibe uma mensagem de erro bem feia. Além disso, todo o progresso du usuário é perdido e ele tem que começar de novo. Você pode melhorar isso criando uma nova função que lê um número do teclado e só retorna quando for informado um valor válido.

Exemplo:

```py
def ler_numero(mensagem, minimo, maximo):
    while True:
        try:
            valor = int(input(mensagem))
        except ValueError:
            print('Valor inválido')
            continue

        if valor >= minimo and valor <= maximo:
            return valor

        print(f'O valor deve estar entre {minimo} e {maximo}')

porta_escolhida = ler_numero('Número da porta: ', 1, 3)
```

### Usabilidade pt 2

A mensagem "Deseja trocar?" sugere que o usuário deve escrever "sim", "y" ou algo do tipo, mas seu código espera um número. Para este caso, crie uma outra função que fica perguntando ao usuário até ele informar uma entrada válida, e que exibe uma mensagem mais informativa.

Exemplo:

```py
def ler_opcao(mensagem, opcoes_validas):
    while True:
        entrada = input(mensagem)

        if entrada in opcoes_validas:
            return entrada

        print('Entrada inválida')

deseja_trocar = ler_opcao('Deseja trocar de porta? (s/n) ', ['s', 'n'])
```

### Recursos da linguagem

Se você estiver usando a versão mais recente do Python, você pode optar pelas [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) em vez da função `format`, pois geralmente torna o código mais legível.

### Boas práticas

Utilize a idioma [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).

### Consistência

Você usou duas funções diferentes (`randint` e `randrange`) para obter um número aleatório de 1 a 3. Por que duas maneiras diferentes de fazer a mesma coisa? Seja consistente!

### Lógica e requisitos

Pelo o que eu pude entender da descrição do jogo, as etapas deveriam ser:

1. O usuário escolhe uma das três portas
2. O apresentador revela o bode de uma das portas restantes
3. O usuário opta se quer ou não trocar de porta
4. O apresentador revela o conteúdo da porta do usuário

O que seu programa faz:

1. Sorteia automaticamente a porta do usuário sem perguntar a ele
2. Se a porta sorteada é a porta do carro, informa que o usuário ganhou e encerra a rodada
3. Se a porta não é a sorteada, pergunta se o usuário quer trocar sem sequer dizer qual era a porta dele
4. Informa o resultado

Ou seja, o fluxo do seu programa está bem diferente do que deveria ser.