# Regex para dar match na primeira ocorrência antes de uma palavra

Tags: python, regex

Minha string é o seguinte:

```
\questao{1}

\begin{enumerate}
todos os tipos de caracteres
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}       -------> APENAS este deve dar match
todos os tipos de caracteres
\end{enumerate}

\questao{2}
```

Estou tentando fazer um regex que consiga identificar **apenas** a primeira ocorrência de `\begin{enumerate}` antes de cada `\questao`.

Quebrei muita a cabeça, porém o máximo que cheguei foi o *match* no primeiro `\begin{enumerate}` quando não tinha nada entre ele e o `\questao`. Porém no caso que necessito, ele terá algumas linhas preenchidas abaixo do `\begin{enumerate}`.

Comment: Seria essa a expressão regular? `/(\\begin\{enumerate\})(?=\s\\end\{enumerate\}\s\s\\questao\{\d+\}$)/`  Funcionando em [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zXMKMb/2)

Comment: Só um update na demo do @Marconi no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zXMKMb/3), pois se entendi bem a pergunta seria sem o $ no final: `(\\begin\{enumerate\})(?=\s\\end\{enumerate\}\s\s\\questao\{\d+\})`

Comment: @Marconi e @danieltakeshi, o detalhe é que as expressões que vcs sugeriram não consideram o caso em que há algum texto entre o `begin` e o `end` (veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/zXMKMb/8) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/zXMKMb/9)).

Answer (score 2):

Para todos os testes abaixo, vou considerar esta string:

```
texto = r"""
\questao{1}

\begin{enumerate}
esse não
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
esse sim
\end{enumerate}

\questao{2}

\begin{enumerate}
esse também não
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
esse também sim
\end{enumerate}

\questao{3}
"""
```

Então você quer pegar somente os `\begin{enumerate}` que estão imediatamente antes de alguma `\questao` (no exemplo acima, são os que contém os trechos "esse sim" e "esse também sim").

Para isso você pode usar o [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), que serve para trabalhar com expressões regulares.

---

Uma primeira alternativa seria usar esta - longa e complicada - regex:

```py
import re

r = re.compile(r'\\begin\{enumerate\}(?:(?!\\begin\{enumerate\}).)+\\end\{enumerate\}(?=(?:(?!\\\w+\{\w+\}).)+\\questao\{\d+\})', re.DOTALL)
resultados = r.findall(texto)
for res in resultados:
    print(res)
```

Como pode ver, a regex é bem complexa. Ela começa simples, com `\\begin\{enumerate\}`, que serve para pegar o trecho `\begin{enumerate}` do texto. Note que os caracteres `\`, `{` e `}` devem ser escapados com `\`, já que eles [possuem significado especial em regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special), e para que eles sejam interpretados como os próprios caracteres, devemos usar o escape.

Depois temos `(?:(?!\\begin\{enumerate\}).)+`. Explicando de dentro para fora:

- o ponto (`.`) corresponde a [(quase) qualquer caractere](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), pois por padrão ele não corresponde à quebras de linha. Mas como eu usei a [*flag* `DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), ele passa a pegar as quebras de linha também.
- o trecho `(?!\\begin\{enumerate\})` é um [*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que verifica se algo **não** existe à frente. No caso, ele verifica se não há outro `\begin{enumerate}` logo à frente (evitando assim que ele "invada" outro `\begin{enumerate}`).

O truque do *lookahead* é que ele só verifica o que tem na frente, mas depois volta para onde estava e continua avaliando a regex. Ou seja, primeiro a regex verifica que não há outro `\begin{enumerate}` à frente, e depois volta para onde estava e avalia o ponto (que pode ser qualquer caractere). E tudo isso está entre parênteses e com o quantificador `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências). Ou seja, ele verifica isso várias vezes, até encontrar o `\end{enumerate}`.

Depois temos um *lookahead*: o trecho entre `(?=....)`, que serve para verificar se algo existe à frente. Dentro deste *lookahead*, eu faço algo similar ao que foi feito anteriormente:

- há o *negative lookahead* `(?!\\\w+\{\w+\})`, que verifica se não tem alguma outra estrutura do tipo `\algumacoisa{alguma coisa}` (o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` corresponde a letras, números ou o caractere `_`, então `\w+` é um ou mais destes caracteres).
- este *negative lookahead* é usado juntamente com o ponto e o `+`, garantindo que eu posso ter um ou mais caracteres, desde que não sejam `\algumacoisa{alguma coisa}`
- por fim, eu chego no trecho que corresponde a `\questao{x}`, sendo que `x` pode ser um ou mais dígitos (`\d+`)

Resumindo, a regex procura por `\begin{enumerate}`, seguido de um ou mais caracteres (verificando antes se não há outro `\begin{enumerate}` à frente), seguido de `\end{enumerate}`, desde que tudo isso esteja seguido de um ou mais caracteres (verificando antes se não é `algumacoisa{alguma coisa}`), seguido de `\questao{x}`.

O [método `findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) retorna uma lista com todas as ocorrências da regex encontradas no texto. O detalhe é que os parênteses usados estão na forma `(?:`, que os torna um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). Eu fiz isso porque se eu não usar `?:`, os parênteses formam um grupo de captura, e `findall` retorna os grupos quando estes estão presentes. Para evitar isso e retornar todo o trecho encontrado, eu uso os grupos de não-captura.

A saída é:

```
\begin{enumerate}
esse sim
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
esse também sim
\end{enumerate}
```

Outra alternativa é usar o [método `finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer), que retorna um iterador de *matches*, que você pode usar para obter mais informações de cada trecho encontrado:

```py
import re

r = re.compile(r'\\begin\{enumerate\}(?:(?!\\begin\{enumerate\}).)+\\end\{enumerate\}(?=(?:(?!\\\w+\{\w+\}).)+\\questao\{\d+\})', re.DOTALL)
for m in r.finditer(texto):
    print('Trecho "{}" encontrado entre as posições {} e {}'.format(m.group(), m.start(), m.end()))
```

A saída é:

```
Trecho "\begin{enumerate}
esse sim
\end{enumerate}" encontrado entre as posições 59 e 101
Trecho "\begin{enumerate}
esse também sim
\end{enumerate}" encontrado entre as posições 169 e 219
```

---

Outra alternativa é obter separadamente cada "bloco" como uma lista, e analisar os elementos um a um:

```py
r = re.compile(r'\\begin\{(\w+)\}.*?\\end\{\1\}|\\(?!begin|end)\w+\{\w+\}', re.DOTALL)
questao_regex = re.compile(r'^\\questao{\d+}$')
partes = [m.group() for m in r.finditer(texto)]
qtd = len(partes) # quantidade de partes encontradas
for i, parte in enumerate(partes):
    # é um begin{enumerate}, não é o último elemento e o próximo é uma questao
    if parte.startswith(r'\begin{enumerate}') and i < qtd - 1 and questao_regex.match(partes[i + 1]):
        print(parte)
```

Agora a regex principal começa com `\\begin\{(\w+)\}` (ou seja, `\begin{alguma coisa}`), sendo que esse "alguma coisa" é `\w+` (um ou mais letras, números ou `_`). Repare que o `\w+` está entre parênteses, formando assim um grupo de captura. Isso será útil para verificar o `\\end\{\1\}`, pois `\1` refere-se ao que foi capturado neste grupo (ou seja, é o mesmo "alguma coisa" que estava no `begin`). Eu usei `\1` pois refere-se ao primeiro grupo de captura (os grupos são numerados de acordo com a ordem em que aparecem na regex).

Com isso eu garanto que estou pegando o `end` correspondente ao `begin` (assumindo que não há estruturas com o mesmo nome aninhadas, pois [neste caso a regex não funcionará direito](https://regex101.com/r/VBNGZW/2)).

Depois temos o caractere `|`, [que significa **ou**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Depois temos um *negative lookahead* que garante que o que temos depois não é nem `begin` nem `end`, e então temos `\w+\{\w+\}` (assim eu pego todos os blocos que não são `begin` nem `end`, como o `question`, por exemplo).

Também criei uma outra regex para verificar especificamente `\questao{x}`. É parecida com a alternativa anterior, a diferença é que adicionei os marcadores `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim eu garanto que a string não pode ter nenhum outro caractere antes ou depois.

Por fim, eu uso `finditer` para obter os *matches* e crio uma lista com as strings encontradas (usando a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052)). Depois eu percorro esta lista e para cada item eu verifico se ele é um `\begin{enumerate}` e se o próximo elemento é `\questao{x}` (usando a regex específica já mencionada). A saída é:

```
\begin{enumerate}
esse sim
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
esse também sim
\end{enumerate}
```

---

Só lembrando que, apesar de funcionar para este caso, regex nem sempre é a melhor ferramenta para fazer *parsing* de textos estruturados como HTML e LaTex. Como eu já disse acima, os códigos acima não lidam bem com estruturas aninhadas - e nesse caso, até daria para usar [regex recursivas](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html), instalando o [módulo `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (pois o módulo `re` não suporta este recurso), mas acho que não vale a pena a complicação.

No seu caso específico, talvez seja melhor tentar usar [libs específicas para trabalhar com LaTex](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+latex+parser).

Answer (score 0):

Tente essa regex para capturar somente a última ocorrência de `\begin` antes da cada ocorrência de `\questao`:

```
(?:.|\s)*?(\\begin{.*?})(?:\s\\end{enumerate}\s*?)(\\questao.*)
```

[Você pode ver seu funcionamento aqui](https://regex101.com/r/MEpyOz/3/)

---

**Explicação:**

- `(?:.|\s)*?` Essa regex ignora todo o conteúdo até uma ocorrência de captura válida através de um [non-capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)
- `(\\begin{.*?})` Captura o ultimo `\begin{x}` sendo `x` qualquer caractere que está entre `{}`
- `(?:\s\\end{enumerate}\s*?)` Ignora todos os caracteres até `\questao` através de um [non-capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) que ignora uma quebra de linha `\s`, a sequência `\end{enumerate}` e também as quebras de linhas seguintes `\s*`
- `(\\questao.*)` Captura `\questao` e todo conteúdo até o final da linha

Comment: Vc está considerando `begin{qualquer coisa}`, mas pelo que entendi, a pergunta só quer `begin{enumerate}`. Além disso, vc não está considerando os casos em que há algum texto entre o `begin` e o `end`, veja: https://regex101.com/r/MEpyOz/6/

Comment: milking the dead cow r u?