# Alterar o valor de um número em uma matriz sem saber a posição (índice) no Python

Tags: python, matriz

Olá,
como faço para alterar o valor de um número em uma matriz quando não sei qual o seu índice e pode acontecer de existir mais de um valor a ser alterado?
Por exemplo, se eu tiver a matriz:

```
[[4,5,3,15,4],
 [20,17,3,4,56],
 [5,6,2,90,32],
 [18,7,1,8,13],
 [0,20,30,4,7]]
```

E eu quero que todos os valor que sejam menores ou iguais 4 sejam alterados pra 10, como faço? Especificamente uma estrutura de repetição, pois a matriz pode ter diferente tamanho dependendo do caso.
Eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
lista  = [[4,5,3,15,4],
          [20,17,3,4,56],
          [5,6,2,90,32],
          [18,7,1,8,13],
          [0,20,30,4,7]]
numero <= 4
if numero in lista:
    lista[lista.index(4)] = 10    
print (lista)
```

Porém, a estrutura de repetição não funciona... A saída deveria ser:

```
 [[10,5,10,15,10],
  [20,17,10,10,56],
  [5,6,10,90,32],
  [18,7,10,8,13],
  [10,20,30,10,7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

O lista.index() retornará apenas o menor índice em que este número ocorre, use um laço for para alterar os valores.

```
lista  = [[4,5,3,15,4],
          [20,17,3,4,56],
          [5,6,2,90,32],
          [18,7,1,8,13],
          [0,20,30,4,7]]

for i in range(0,len(lista)):
    for j in range(0,len(lista[i])):
        if lista[i][j] <= 4:
            lista[i][j] = 10

print(lista)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. A linha `numero <= 4` não faz muito sentido, não está a fazer absolutamente nada.
2. Lembra-te que tens uma lista de listas, logo a lógica dentro do for não está correta, tu deves aceder a dois indices, ao da sublista e ao do número dentro dessa sulista para que consigas **comparar**/alterar o seu valor.
3. `lista.index(...)` apenas te retorna o indíce da primeira ocorrência de um determinado elemento (4, neste caso) dentro de uma lista

Usando ciclo `for`, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) e fazendo da maneira [`pythonica`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico/192347#192347):

```
lista = [[4,5,3,15,4],
         [20,17,3,4,56],
         [5,6,2,90,32],
         [18,7,1,8,13],
         [0,20,30,4,7]]

for idx1, i in enumerate(lista): # percorrer elementos (sublistas), e respetivos indices, contidos na lista principal
  for idx2, j in enumerate(lista[idx1]): # percorrer elementos e respetivos indices contidos na sublista, aqui enumerate(i) tambem daria
    if(j <= 4):
      lista[idx1][idx2] = 10 # alterar valor

print(lista) # [[10, 5, 10, 15, 10], [20, 17, 10, 10, 56], [5, 6, 10, 90, 32], [18, 7, 10, 8, 13], [10, 20, 30, 10, 7]]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/EssentialSimultaneousAdmin)

Que usando [*list compreension*](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) pode ser reduzido para uma linha:

```
lista = [[4,5,3,15,4],
         [20,17,3,4,56],
         [5,6,2,90,32],
         [18,7,1,8,13],
         [0,20,30,4,7]]

lista = [[10 if j <= 4 else j for j in i] for i in lista]
# [[10, 5, 10, 15, 10], [20, 17, 10, 10, 56], [5, 6, 10, 90, 32], [18, 7, 10, 8, 13], [10, 20, 30, 10, 7]]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/HauntingLonelyCompilers)

Com [numpy e place](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html):

```
import numpy as np

lista = [[4,5,3,15,4],
         [20,17,3,4,56],
         [5,6,2,90,32],
         [18,7,1,8,13],
         [0,20,30,4,7]]

arr = np.asarray(lista)
np.place(arr, arr<=4, [10])

print(arr) # [[10 5 10 15 10] [20 17 10 10 56] [ 5 6 10 90 32] [18 7 10 8 13] [10 20 30 10 7]]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/WjJ4Ys)