# Obter dados do tipo String de um documento CSV

Tags: python, csv

Tenho um documento CSV (Excel) com e-mails válidos e inválidos. E eu queria pegar os valores dos campos em forma de *string*, mas o seguinte código dá o retorno mostrado mais abaixo:

```
import csv
import re

ifile  = open('ead.csv', "r")
read = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
csvArray = []

for row in read : 
    csvArray.append(row)
print(csvArray[0:10])
```

Retorno:

```
[['naoinformado@naoinformado.com.br'], ['lucas.spereia@outlook.com'], ['ronaldo_123@hotmail.cm.br'], ['jessica_fonseca164@hotmail.com'], ['leidimara.vv@outlook.com.br'], ['patriciaazevedo@yahoo.com.br'], ['dallilass123@outlook.com'], ['michellybecker@hotmail.com.br'], ['mylena@campelo.com.br'], ['vitor@1257gmail.com.br']]
>>>
```

Mas eu preciso que os resultados apareçam apenas `'email@test.com'` sem o `'[]'`, para que eu possa validá-los.

Comment: Podes só `', '.join(ifile.read().splitlines())`, ficas com, "email1, email2, email3, ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você lê um arquivo CSV, o objeto `row` em:

```
for row in read: ...
```

será uma lista com todas as colunas encontradas. Como seu arquivo possui apenas uma coluna com o e-mail, o valor de `row` será uma lista com um elemento. Ao fazer `csvArray.append(row)` você adiciona toda a lista em `csvArray` e não apenas o valor do e-mail. Sabendo que sempre será a primeira coluna o e-mail, poderia fazer:

```
import csv
import re

ifile  = open('ead.csv', "r")
read = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
csvArray = []

for row in read : 
    csvArray.append(row[0])
print(csvArray[0:10])
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/UnrealisticForcefulSuperuser)</sup>

Mas uma solução mais [*pythonica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878) para o seu problema seria:

```
import csv

def get_emails_from_csv(filename):
    with open(filename) as stream:
        reader = csv.reader(stream, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for line in reader:
            yield line[0]

emails = get_emails_from_csv('ead.csv')

print( list(emails) )
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DimpledGrowlingScript)</sup>