# Como multiplicar a quantidade de listas por um inteiro?

Tags: python-3.x, matriz

Se eu tiver um inteiro em input e uma lista em input, é possível multiplicar o inteiro pela lista?

```
M = int(input())

C = (eval('[' + input() + ']'))
```

Isto é, para ter ''M'' listas de acordo com o inteiro que eu colocar em M, dai eu va formando as listas.O número inteiro M define a quantidade de listas.

ex: `M =2` `C = [1,2,3]
                [4,5,6]`

Comment: Li e reli varias vezes o título da pergunta e o texto da pergunta (acredito que muita gente fez isso) em si e ainda não consegui compreender o que você realmente deseja. Poderia refazer seu texto?

Comment: Ok, ficou mais claro?

Comment: Você não está errando sua operação de multiplicar?
A resposta não seria 2,4,6?

Comment: Não, é como se M = 2, eu poderia colocar valores aleatórios mas apenas em 2 listas. O número M define o número de listas.

Comment: Você através de um M define quantas lista você vai ler? É isso?

Comment: Exato, porém todas com um mesmo número de elementos.

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: como eu faço isso,  ''M'' listas com 3 variáveis. Sendo M um input incial, e depois as listas o segundo input.

Comment: Todas as listas em apenas um input? Existe métodos mais fáceis para isso.

Comment: Isso. Tipo x = int(input()) ; x=10 ; c = eval('[' + input() + ']') ; ''2,3,4 ..... 5,8,2'' 10 listas dessa

Comment: Obrigatoriamente deve ser assim?

Comment: não não, esse foi o jeito que eu pensei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira melhor de fazer isso, sempre procure fazer algo em Python da maneira mais fácil possível.

```
n = int(input()) #Aqui você lê o numero de listas que você deseja.
colecao = [] #Aqui você cria uma matriz vazia.

for _ in range(n): #Um laco de repeticao para ler as listas.
  x = list(map(int,input().split(','))) #Lê a lista, splita ela pela virgula e transforma tudo em int, depois transforma no tipo lista.
  colecao.append(x) #Adiciono ao fim da coleção
print(colecao) #Printo a coleção
```

Exemplo de Entradas e Saídas:

```
    3  
1,2,3  
4,5,6  
7,8,9 
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se for a resposta que deseja por favor confirme ela.

Comment: Uma última dúvida, eu poderia somar os elementos de uma só posição das listas a seguir? como 1+4+7 (posição 0)

Comment: Cria um laço de repetição que passe por todas as listas e uma variavel para guardar a soma.

Inicie ela com 0, passe o loop por todas as listas somando.

Comment: Obrigadasso cara.

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito [*Pythonico*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico)

```
n = int( input() )
colecao = [ list( map(int, input().split(',')) ) for _ in range(n) ]
print(colecao)
```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/@wellmotta/300478-stackoverflow), [GitHub Gist para futura referência](https://gist.github.com/wellmotta/9a341bac1ddc71e1173c857b8dedab67)

#### Referência

- [*O que é código pythônico?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico)