# Exibir apenas as palavras que possuem um número par de vogais dentro de uma frase

Tags: python

Preciso fazer esse código no qual percorre uma lista e imprime ao usuário as palavras que possuem quantidade par de vogais. Segue o código:

```
frase = ["Foi magnifica a festa ontem."]

palavras = 0
vPalavras = 0
vogais = "aeiouAEIOU"

# separar palavra por palavra
for i in range(len(frase)):
  palavras = frase[i].split()

# descobrir quais palavras possuem vogais em par
for i in range(len(palavras)):
  for char in palavras[i]:
    if char in vogais:
        vPalavras += 1
    if vPalavras % 2 == 0:
      print(palavras[i])
```

Então, ele de fato retorna algo para mim, porém são só as duas primeiras palavras, ignorando "festa" e "ontem".

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está, por muito pouco, quase funcionando.

O primeiro problema, e o principal deles, é que **você não reinicia a contagem de vogais a cada palavra**. Da forma que fez, a contagem irá se acumulando; então, ao invés de considerar palavra por palavra, você acaba considerando sempre desde o início da *string*.

Para resolver isso, basta adicionar um `vPalavras = 0` sempre que mudar de palavra.

```
frase = ["Foi magnifica a festa ontem."]

palavras = 0
vPalavras = 0
vogais = "aeiouAEIOU"

# separar palavra por palavra
for i in range(len(frase)):
  palavras = frase[i].split()

# descobrir quais palavras possuem vogais em par
for i in range(len(palavras)):
  vPalavras = 0  # Reinicia o contador a cada palavra
  for char in palavras[i]:
    if char in vogais:
        vPalavras += 1
    if vPalavras % 2 == 0:
      print(palavras[i])
```

Desta forma, a saída passa a ser:

```
Foi
Foi
magnifica
magnifica
magnifica
magnifica
festa
festa
ontem.
ontem.
ontem.
```

Temos todas as palavras que queremos, mas repetidas. Por quê? Bom, perceba que a palavra se repete exatamente o mesmo número de vogais que ela possui. `Foi` possui duas vogais, aparecendo duas vezes; `magnifica` possui quatro vogais, repetindo quatro vezes. Isso se dá porque **você fez a condição `if vPalavras % 2 == 0` dentro do laço que percorre os caracteres da palavra**. Assim, para cada caractere, sempre que o total de vogais for par, a palavra será exibida. Não queremos isso, então basta remover um nível de indentação desta condicional, deixando-a dentro, apenas, do laço que percorre as palavras:

```
frase = ["Foi magnifica a festa ontem."]

palavras = 0
vPalavras = 0
vogais = "aeiouAEIOU"

# separar palavra por palavra
for i in range(len(frase)):
  palavras = frase[i].split()

# descobrir quais palavras possuem vogais em par
for i in range(len(palavras)):
  vPalavras = 0  # Reinicia o contador a cada palavra
  for char in palavras[i]:
    if char in vogais:
        vPalavras += 1
  if vPalavras % 2 == 0:  # Aqui removi um nível de indentação
    print(palavras[i])
```

E, com isso, o resultado será:

```
Foi
magnifica
festa
ontem.
```

Eureca! Temos o resultado desejado.

---

**Mas por que não outras melhorias no seu código?**

Você começa definindo a frase:

```
frase = ["Foi magnifica a festa ontem."]
```

Porém, dada a presença dos colchetes, você estará criando uma lista de *strings*. Se, por ventura, precisar de mais frases, talvez até seja interessante fazer isso, mas como possui apenas uma, basta você definir como *string* única:

```
frase = "Foi magnifica a festa ontem."
```

Para percorrer todas as frases, você fez:

```
for i in range(len(frase)):
    palavras = frase[i].split()
```

Dificilmente no Python você precisará fazer `range(len(...))` para percorrer alguma coisa. Isso não é legível - e se não é legível, não é [pythonico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878). Você poderia muito bem substituir por:

```
for frase in frases:
    palavras = frase.split()
```

Mas, como não temos mais uma lista de *strings*, basta você fazer:

```
palavras = frase.split()
```

Para percorrer as palavras, também, não é necessário `range(len(palavras))`; um `for palavra in palavras` basta.

```
for palavra in palavras:
    quantidade = 0
    for vogal in 'aeiouAEIOU':
        quantidade += palavra.count(vogal)
```

Perceba que, ao invés de percorrer cada caractere da palavra e verificar se é uma vogal, percorri cada vogal e contei quantas vezes ela aparece na palavra, somando ao total. Você pode ainda simplificar esse código utilizando *list comprehension*:

```
for palavra in palavras:
    quantidade = sum(palavra.count(vogal) for vogal in 'aeiouAEIOU')
```

> Isso desconsiderando vogais acentuadas, tal como á, ã, é, etc.

Assim, seu código poderia ser apenas:

```
frase = "Foi magnifica a festa ontem."
palavras = frase.split()
for palavra in palavras:
    quantidade = sum(palavra.count(vogal) for vogal in 'aeiouAEIOU')
    if quantidade % 2 == 0:
        print(palavra)
```

Comment: nossa, era só iniciar a variável... muito obrigada por todas as dicas! ;)

Answer (score 0):

O seu erro é simples.

```
 if vPalavras % 2 == 0:
```

esse código quer dizer, se a palavra *resto* 2 for igual a zero logo ele imprime, magnifica tem 4 vogais, logo 4%2 = 0, então ele imprime. sugiro utilizar a nomenclatura diferente.

```
 if vPalavras / 2 == 1:
```

assim você garante que a divisão das palavras é SEMPRE 2 e não um numero par

Comment: Acabei errando ao fazer a pergunta. Eu gostaria de retornar todas as palavras nas quais os numeros de vogais sejam pares, ou seja: "Foi", "magnifica", "festa" e "ontem", porém só retorna as duas primeiras.

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Seja bem-vinda ao Python.

Incialmente seu código cria uma lista com uma string somente dentro, eu sugiro criar somente a string, porque a lista é confusa aqui:

```
frase = "Foi magnifica a festa ontem."  # removido [] para não criar uma lista
```

Outra sugestão que serve para a sua vida toda no python é evitar usar `for i in range(len(palavras)):` -- o `for` do python já itera nos elementos diretos, então raramente você vai precisar do índice, na maioria das o que vezes você quer é usar `for palavra in palavras:` e iterar direto nas palavras e não no índice.

EDITANDO: De acordo com o comentário abaixo, parece que "pares de vogais" significa "número par de vogais", então é só contar quantas vogais tem na palavra.

```
palavras = frase.split()
for palavra in palavras:
    if numero_de_vogais(palavra) % 2 == 0:
        print(palavra)

def numero_de_vogais(texto):
    return len([letra for letra in texto if letra in vogais])
```

Tem uma outra forma usando o `sum`:

```
def numero_de_vogais(texto):
    return sum(1 for letra in texto if letra in vogais)
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pelas dicas! Não era bem isso, quando disse "total de pares de vogais" seria para imprimir todas as palavras que as vogais são pares. No exemplo, por exemplo, deveria ser "Foi", "magnifica", "festa" e "ontem". Mas só aparece as duas primeiras

Comment: @H.Lamarr editei a resposta, veja se está de acordo agora