# nao esta acumulando valores nas listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

lista1=list()

lista2=list()

def lê_e_verifica():
    """ lê um  inteiro e verifica se esta correto retorna o inteiro lido"""

```
while True:
     try:
        inteiros= int(input("entre com numeros1 "))
        inteiros= int(input("entre com numeros2 "))
        break # se deu certo sai do laço
    except ValueError: 
        print("deu errado por favor digite novamente ")
return inteiros

for a in range (5):
    lista1[a]= lê_e_verifica  
for r in range (5):
    lista2[r]= lê_e_verifica
```

lê_e_verifica()

""" quero que o usuario entre 5 numeros na lista1, e 5 lista 2 se ele digitar algo que nao int ele deve digitar novamente"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tornar seu código mais "[pythônico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico)" usando [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Deste modo, você não precisará inicializar as variáveis `lista1` e `lista2` antes de utilizá-las e poderá atribuir os valores da lista em apenas uma linha.

```
# Atribuindo valores para lista1 e lista2 com list comprehension
lista1 = [le_inteiro() for i in range(5)]
lista2 = [le_inteiro() for i in range(5)]
```

Segue como ficaria o código completo:

```
def le_inteiro():
    while True:
        try:
            inteiro = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))
            return inteiro
        except ValueError:
            print('O valor informado não é válido, tente novamente.')

# Fazendo as atribuições nas listas.
print('Preencha os valores para lista 1:')
lista1 = [le_inteiro() for i in range(5)]

print('Preencha os valores para lista 2:')
lista2 = [le_inteiro() for i in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Olá, tudo bem?
Se você quer preencher duas listas com 5 valores inteiros em cada, permita-me fazer algumas observações no seu código.
Eu não sou experiente, portanto, se alguém quiser me corrigir ao falar besteiras, eu agradeço :D

Sua função *lê_e_verifica* contém acentuação, isso não é recomendado, embora o Python não reclame. Tente sempre evitar esses acentos nas definições de funções, métodos, variáveis, etc.
Dentro da sua função, você está escrevendo duas vezes em cima da mesma variável *inteiros* e depois retornando ela, ou seja, você coloca o valor 1 nela, e depois coloca o valor 2 apagando o valor 1. Sugiro que você mantenha uma única declaração para essa variável.

```
# Sempre deixe um espaço nas atribuições, 'a = b'.
lista1 = []
lista2 = []
# Sua função.
def le_e_verifica():
    while True:
        try:
            inteiros = int(input('Entre com o número'))
            return inteiros
        except ValueError:
            print('O valor informado não é válido, tente novamente.')
# Fazendo as atribuições nas listas.
for c in range(5):
    lista1.append(le_e_verifica())
    lista2.append(le_e_verifica())
```

Se você quiser, pode por exemplo passar um parâmetro para a função dizendo qual das listas será preenchida, ou coisa assim.
Quando você tenta chamar a função sem utilizar os parênteses, na verdade você está associando a função a variável, e não chamando a função como você espera, observe:

```
# Associa a função a variável 'A'.
A = le_e_verifica
# Agora você pode chamar através de 'A'.
resultado = A()
```

Espero que isso possa te ajudar. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem se você quer que a função retorne dois números inteiros ou um só, mas enfim, a indentação está desorganizada, e você está adicionando de maneira errada. A maneira correta seria:

```
for i in range(5):
    lista1.append(le_e_verifica())
for j in range(5):
    lista2.append(le_e_verifica())
```

Ah, e evite colocar acentos em nomes de funções e variáveis.