# Existe algum método no Python semelhante ao x.find(string), mas que retorne todas as ocorrências?

Tags: python, string

Por exemplo, tenho uma string com várias ocorrências de `a`:

```
a = 'abcdefhanmakaoa'
```

Se eu usar o método `find`, só consigo encontrar o índice da primeira ocorrência. Existe algum método/função nativa que me retorne todas as ocorrências?

Comment: Não, você tem que escrever algo que ache todas para você.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado

Comment: na verdade, dá pra argumentar o que  o `re.finditer` faz isso - mas ele é tão flexível  que o boilerplatezinho que você tem que por em volta dele pra ter os índices pode ser interpretado por "você tem que fazer".  A resposta do @hkotsubo tem um exemplo de uso do finditer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você possui duas formas de fazer isso. Uma usando regex, para criar um iterator com todas as ocorrências. A outra é usando força bruta em uma função, que no caso seria algo como:

```
inicio = 0
termo = "a"
indexes = []

while inicio < len(a):
    resultado = a[inicio:].find(termo)
    if resultado == -1: 
        break
    indexes.append(resultado + inicio)
    inicio += resultado + 1
```

Assim a lista `indexes` vai guardar todas as ocorrências.

Você pode, inclusive, guardar isso em uma função chamada `findAll`, para usar sempre que precisar fazer essa operação.

### Utilizando argumentos do método find()

Assim como o @jsbueno mencionou, é possível adicionar diretamente no método find() o parâmetro de início, o que faria o código ficar assim:

```
while inicio < len(a):
        resultado = a.find(termo, inicio)
        if resultado == -1: 
            break
        indexes.append(resultado)
        inicio = resultado + 1
    return indexes
```

### Eficiência computacional das opções

Criando-se 2 funções para cada opção acima, e medindo com o módulo timeit:

```
print(timeit.timeit(fun1, number = 1000000))
print(timeit.timeit(fun2, number = 1000000))
```

É possível perceber que o segundo método, utilizando a função find() diretamente, ao invés de usar o slice para strings, é mais eficiente.
prints:

```
2.979384636011673
2.4164228980080225
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado :)

Comment: bacana o algoritmo!  Está certinho e bem legível - e eu mesmo fazia assim acho que até o ano passado  - daí dscobri que o próprio método `.find` aceita um segundo argumento, com o deslocamento de "inicio" da busca.

Isso facilita muito justamente esses casos, evita a operação relativamente cara de fatiar uma string para o próximo `find` e a possibilidade de erro ao se calcular os deslocamentos para os laços seguintes. 

Talvez seja legal você completar a resposta com um segundo exemplo usando essa forma de passar o valor de `resultado + 1` diretamente no segundo parâmetro do "find".

Comment: @jsbueno, atualizei o código com a sua sugestão, e realmente, da forma que comentou, o processamento é mais eficiente

Comment: @KaelSouza, caso minha resposta tenha respondido sua pergunta, marque por favor como a resposta correta :)

Answer (score 4):

Para este caso específico, em que você só quer buscar a ocorrência de uma única letra, você pode percorrer a string com [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate), assim pode ter de uma só vez o índice e o respectivo caractere naquele índice.

E como quer criar uma lista com o resultado, pode usar a [sintaxe de *list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
a = 'abcdefhanmakaoa'
# "i" é o índice, "c" é o caractere naquele índice
indices = [i for i, c in enumerate(a) if c == 'a']
print(indices)
```

A linha que cria a lista de índices (`indices = [ ...`) é um [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), e é equivalente a fazer um `for` "tradicional" de outras linguagens:

```
indices = []
for i, c in enumerate(a):
    if c == 'a':
        indices.append(i)
```

Apesar de serem equivalentes, o *list comprehension*, além de mais sucinto, é a [forma mais *pythônica* de se fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192388/112052).

A saída é uma lista com todos os índices que correspondem a uma letra "a":

> [0, 7, 10, 12, 14]

---

O código acima funciona apenas para os casos em que você quer buscar ocorrências de uma única letra.

Para casos mais complicados/gerais, em que você quer buscar ocorrências de uma palavra, por exemplo (ou critérios mais complicados, como "começa com uma letra minúscula ou número e tem pelo menos N caracteres, etc"), uma alternativa é usar regex, através do [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

a = 'abcdefhanmakaoa'
indices = [m.start(0) for m in re.finditer('a', a)]
print(indices)
```

`finditer` retorna todos os *matches* obtidos (também usando a sintaxe de *list comprehension* para o retorno já estar em uma lista). Como a regex usada é `'a'` (a própria letra "a"), será retornada uma lista com todos os *matches* que correspondem a esta letra. Em seguida, `start(0)` retorna a posição inicial do *match*. Com isso, você obtém os índices de todas as letras "a" da string.

A lista de índices é a mesma obtida no primeiro exemplo. Mas como a expressão a ser testada é muito simples (a letra `a`), **neste caso específico eu acho um exagero usar regex**. Mas fica registrada a alternativa, caso você precise de casos mais complicados do que pegar somente uma letra específica.

---

Outro bônus de usar regex nos casos mais complicados é que você pode obter também o índice final:

```
a = 'abcdeafabc'
indices = [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer('abc', a)]
print(indices)
```

No caso, estou procurando as ocorrências de `abc` e retornando uma lista de tuplas (note os parênteses em volta de `m.start(0)` e `m.end(0)`, eles [delimitam uma tupla](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple)), sendo que cada tupla contém o índice inicial e final de `abc`:

> [(0, 3), (7, 10)]

Repare que os índices seguem a regra *start inclusive/end exclusive* ("início incluso, final não-incluso"). Por exemplo: a primeira ocorrência de `abc` corresponde aos índices 0, 1 e 2 da string, mas o retorno foi `(0, 3)` (o índice final não é "incluso").

Claro que se você quiser apenas o índice inicial, basta usar somente `m.start(0)`, como já explicado anteriormente.

Comment: o seu primeiro exemplo só é capaz de achar ocorrências se o texto a ser buscado tiver uma única letra. 
O "finditer" sim, só ele, e com uma busca por uma palavra em vez de uma letra, seria uma resposta bem legal pra essa pergunta.

Comment: (ok, a pergunta só dá o exemplo de busca de uma letra - mas então vale a pena ressaltar essa limitação)

Comment: @jsbueno De fato, acabei me atendo demais ao caso específico da pergunta. Acrescentei um comentário sobre esta limitação, obrigado!