# Como separar as letras de uma string que estão inseridas em uma lista e colocá-las em uma matriz?

Tags: python, string, lista, matriz

Tenho uma lista com a palavra "teste", disposta de tal forma:

```
['teste','teste','teste','teste','teste']
```

Gostaria de transformar essa lista em uma matriz, na qual as letras ficassem separadas umas das outras:

```
[
  ['t','e','s','t','e']
  ['t','e','s','t','e']
  ['t','e','s','t','e']
  ['t','e','s','t','e']
  ['t','e','s','t','e']
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você pode usar [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) para transformar as strings em listas. Se você faz `list(string)`, o resultado é uma lista na qual cada elemento é um caractere da string. Ex:

```
print(list('teste'))
```

Isso imprime:

> ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e']

Então basta fazer isso para cada elemento da sua lista, e ir adicionando essas listas na sua matriz (sendo que "matriz" nada mais é que uma lista de listas: uma lista na qual cada elemento também é uma lista):

```
lista = ['teste', 'teste', 'teste', 'teste', 'teste']

matriz = [list(palavra) for palavra in lista]
print(matriz)
```

Isso imprime:

> [['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e']]

Note que usei a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.0.html#list-comprehensions), que é mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052). O código acima é equivalente a:

```
lista = ['teste', 'teste', 'teste', 'teste', 'teste']

matriz = []
for palavra in lista:
    matriz.append(list(palavra))

print(matriz)
```

Comment: Muito legal esta resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado! passei muito tempo quebrando a cabeça com essa função list.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma fácil de separar letras em uma string e alocá-las em uma lista é utilizando a função `list()` do Python. Assim:

```
palavras = ['teste','teste','teste','teste','teste']
matriz = []

for palavra in palavras:
    matriz.append(list(palavra))
```

Com isso, se você mandar exibir o conteúdo da lista `matriz`, o resultado vai ser exatamente o que você espera:

```
print(matriz)

[['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'],
 ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'],
 ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'],
 ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'],
 ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e']]
```

A função `list()` percorre cada posição do objeto passado como parâmetro, transforma cada uma dessas posições em um novo objeto e aloca dentro de uma lista. Já o método `.append()` adiciona o parâmetro dado dentro da lista.

Nesse caso, transformamos cada palavra `'teste'` em uma lista `['t','e','s','t','e']` e alocamos dentro da lista `matriz`, que havia sido criada anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['teste','teste','teste','teste','teste']

b = []

for palavra in a:
    linha = []
    for letra in palavra:
        linha.append(letra)
    b.append(linha)

print(b)
```

Output:

`[['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e']]`

Answer (score 1):

Acho que consigo te ajudar dessa forma utilizando o List:

```
testes = ['teste','teste','teste','teste','teste']
testes_separados = []
for teste in testes:
    testes_separados.append(list(teste))

print(teste)
```