# Somar valores de listas com tamanhos diferentes

Tags: python, lista

Tenho duas listas com números e tamanhos variados. Por exemplo:

```
array 1
['1', '142', '33', '33', '9', '2']

array 2
['1', '12', '7', '-2', '39', '11',  '31', '49', '50', '1']
```

Como faço um *loop* para somar o primeiro item da array 1 com o primeiro item da array 2 e assim por diante? Caso alguma delas não possua a quantidade necessária de itens, deverá somar a zero, ficando assim: 1+1, 142+12, 33+7, ..., 2+11, 0+31, 0+49, ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) do módulo [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

Basta passar as duas listas e definir o valor *default* a ser usado para preencher os valores faltantes (no caso, usarei zero).

Como nas suas listas os elementos estão entre aspas, eles na verdade são strings, então eu converto os elementos para números usando [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list1 = ['1', '142', '33', '33', '9', '2']
list2 = ['1', '12', '7', '-2', '39', '11',  '31', '49', '50', '1']

# percorrer as duas listas, preencher os valores faltantes com zero
somas = [int(e1) + int(e2)  for e1, e2 in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=0)]
print(somas) # [2, 154, 40, 31, 48, 13, 31, 49, 50, 1]
```

Com isso podemos percorrer as duas listas simultaneamente, sendo que a cada iteração do `for`, a variável `e1` será um elemento da `lista1`, e `e2` será um elemento da `lista2`. Se as listas tiverem tamanhos diferentes, os valores faltantes são preenchidos com zero (o valor definido por `fillvalue`).

O resultado é:

> [2, 154, 40, 31, 48, 13, 31, 49, 50, 1]

Note que usei a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) para criar a lista de somas. A linha que cria as somas é equivalente a:

```
somas = []
for e1, e2 in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=0):
    somas.append(int(e1) + int(e2))
```

Porém a *list comprehension* é a forma mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052).

Comment: muuuuuito obrigada! agora tudo faz mais sentido
entendi com mais facilidade a forma sem o uso do list comprehension