# Em uma lista de listas, como somar cada item de cada lista com o item de sua respectiva posição?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, arraylist

Por ex minha lista é:

```py
x = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
```

Como posso criar uma nova lista de forma que seus elementos sejam as somas dos elementos correspondentes em cada lista?

```py
y = [1+6,2+7,3+8,4+9,5+0]
```

Comment: Olá Sander! Bem vindo à comunidade! Eu editei sua pergunta para que ficasse mais clara. Por favor analise minha resposta e marque como aceita se é que corresponde às suas expectativas.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/365456/112052

Answer (score 5):

Bom, nesse caso as listas podem possuir diferentes tamanhos, portanto precisamos preencher as posições da menores listas e então somar os valores correspondentes. Podemos fazer isso utilizando `zip_longest` com `fillvalue` para preencher as menores listas:

```py
x = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
from itertools import zip_longest
y = [sum(x) for x in zip_longest(*x, fillvalue=0)]
print(y)
# [7, 9, 11, 13, 5]
```