# Converter string em uma lista em que cada elemento da lista são 3 caracteres da minha string inicial

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista

Gostaria de saber como posso transformar uma *string* em uma lista em que cada elemento dessa lista seja uma *string* com 3 caracteres da *string* original. Portanto se a *string* original era assim `"AAGGGTTGG"` eu obtenho uma lista assim `["AAG","GGT","TGG"]`.

Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
seq = "AAGGGTTGG"
i = 0
codon_lista = []
for i in range(len(seq)):
    codon = seq[i:i+3]
    codon_lista.append(codon)
    i = i + 3
```

Entretanto o resultado disso é algo como:

```
["AAG", "AGG", "GGG", "GGT", "GTT", "TTG", "TGG", "GG", "G"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A instrução `i = i + 3` dentro do `for` não funciona porque esse valor de `i` é sempre sobrescrito pelo próximo valor do `range`. Exemplo:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    i = 100
```

Esse código imprime os números de 0 a 4. Mesmo eu setando o valor de `i` para 100, na próxima iteração ele será sobrescrito pelo próximo valor do `range`. Então não adianta somar 3 ao `i` dentro do *loop*.

A solução é usar um `range` que pula de 3 em 3:

```
seq = "AAGGGTTGG"
codon_lista = []
for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
    codon_lista.append(seq[i:i+3])

print(codon_lista)
```

Repare também que não é preciso inicializar `i = 0` fora do *loop*. O resultado é:

> ['AAG', 'GGT', 'TGG']

---

Se quiser, também pode usar a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052).

```
seq = "AAGGGTTGG"
codon_lista = [ seq[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(seq), 3)]
print(codon_lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

O `for i in range()` recebe como parâmetros um valor inicial, um valor final e um valor para iterar. Resumindo:  `for i in range(val_inicial, val_final, iterador)`. O valor de i é iterado até um valor antes do valor final, ou seja, i varia de `[val_inicial, val_final[`.

Por padrão, itera incrementando de `1` em `1`.

```
>>> for i in range(0, 5):
>>>     print(i)
0
1
2
3
4
```

Isso é o mesmo que escrever `for i in range(0, 5, 1):`.

Para iterar de `3` em `3`, podemos fazer:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 5, 3):
>>>     print(i)
0
3
```

No seu caso, basta mudar para `for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):`.

É possível iterar com valores negativos também, como

```
>>> for i in range(5, 0, -1):
>>>     print(i)
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha essa implementação em Javascript, pode servir de inspiração, e é bem simples, ele percorre letra por letra, e a cada intervalo (3 no seu exemplo) insere em outro array.

```
var seq = "AAGGGTTGG";
var intervalo = 3;

codon_lista = [];
for (var i=0; i<seq.length-1; i++) {
    if (i%intervalo === 0) {
        codon_lista.push(seq.substr(i, intervalo));
    }
}
console.log(codon_lista);
```