# Como criar lista simples a partir de lista composta?

Tags: python, python-3.x

O que está errado aqui? Gostaria que o output fosse `[123, 456, 789]`:

```
a = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
b = []

for num in a:
    x = ''
    for num2 in num:
        x.join(num2)
    b.append(x)

print(b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cada elemento de `a` é uma tupla com 3 números. Para juntá-los, você pode transformá-los em string, juntar tudo com [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) e converter o resultado de volta para número:

```
a = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
b = [int(''.join(str(n) for n in numeros)) for numeros in a]
print(b)
```

Mas se quiser, pode também usar um pouco de matemática para transformar `(1, 2, 3)` em `123`:

```
def juntar_numeros(numeros):
    return sum(n * 10 ** (len(numeros) - 1 - i) for i, n in enumerate(numeros))

a = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]    
b = [juntar_numeros(numeros) for numeros in a]
print(b)
```

A ideia é usar o índice de cada elemento para saber a potência de 10 correspondente. Para isso uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), que permite obter o elemento e o respectivo índice ao mesmo tempo.

O resultado de ambos é a lista `[123, 456, 789]`.

---

Nos códigos acima usei a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052).

Para quem não está acostumado, pode parecer meio difícil de entender. Outro modo de fazer seria:

```
# transformar em string, join e converter para número depois
a = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
b = []

for numeros in a:
    # map converte os números para strings, para poderem serem unidos no join
    b.append(int(''.join(map(str, numeros))))

print(b)
```

---

```
# solução matemática
a = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]

def juntar_numeros(numeros):
    result = 0
    for i, n in enumerate(numeros):
        result += n * 10 ** (len(numeros) - 1 - i)
    return result

b = []
for numeros in a:
    b.append(juntar_numeros(numeros))

print(b)
```