# Python - Ler dados até ponto de demarcação

Tags: python-3.x

Como faço pra ler os dados de um arquivo (de texto ou binário) até **um ponto demarcado** por mim dentro dele? Por exemplo, escrevi um texto e coloquei um **.(ponto)** que separa a primeira da segunda parte. Como faço pra ler só a primeira parte? Só até o ponto?

Comment: Você pode abrir o arquivo para leitura, ir lendo caractere a caractere (ou um conjunto deles) até encontrar o caractere demarcado. Se seu objeto for uma instância de `io.RawIOBase`, como é o retorno de `open`, você pode utilizar o método `read`.

Answer (score 1):

Saudações RetroNietzsche,

Para testar este código, primeiro crie o arquivo "teste.txt" com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
Python é uma linguagem de programação de alto nível, interpretada, de script, 
imperativa, orientada a objetos, funcional, de tipagem dinâmica e forte. #stop
Foi lançada por Guido van Rossum em 1991. 
Wikipédia
```

Segue o método "ler_arquivo" que recebe os parâmetros "parar" e "arquivo".

O funcionamento é bem simples. O método procura em cada linha do arquivo "txt" a string da variável "parar". Remove ela junto com as quebras de linha e os espaços em branco.

Retorna uma lista atualizada como uma string concatenada até o ponto delimitado na variável "parar".

```
arquivo = 'teste.txt'

parar = '#stop'

def ler_arquivo(parar, arquivo):

    lista = []

    arq = open(arquivo, 'r')

    for linha in arq:

        if parar in linha:
            i = linha.index(parar) # indice da marcação para parar
            linha = linha.replace(linha[i:-1],'').strip('\n').strip() # removendo a marcação
            lista.append(linha)
            return ''.join(lista)        
        else:
            lista.append(linha.strip('\n').strip())

    return ''.join(lista)            

    arq.close()


print(ler_arquivo(parar, arquivo))
```

Comment: É completamente desnecessário fazer `arq.readlines()` neste problema; isso irá carregar todo o conteúdo do arquivo em memória e se o arquivo for muito grande será péssimo para a aplicação e para o servidor, podendo travar o sistema. Ao invés, você pode iterar direto sobre `arq`, que é um gerador e irá manter apenas uma linha do arquivo em memória por vez.

Comment: Saudações Anderson, atualizei a resposta com a sua dica. 
Muito obrigado por sua contribuição!

Comment: Se interessar, comentei sobre isso no item 6, bem no final desta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192347/5878).