# Regex para identificar todas as ocorrências de anos

Tags: python, regex

Fiz esse Regex para capturar as ocorrências de anos numa sequência de números (entre 2010-2029).

```
text = '0412020982012'
rg = r'20[1-2][0-9]'
years = re.compile("(%s)" % (rg)).findall(text)
```

Funciona perfeitamente.

Porém caso a string seja `0420202198`, ele não funciona, pois ela pega apenas a ocorrência do 2020, mas não do 2021, devido estar compartilhando os dígitos.

No meu caso, quero pegar sempre os anos identificados mais à direita. Como posso resolver mantendo o uso do Regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
.*(20[1-2][0-9])
```

O grupo 1 será sempre a última sequência `20XX` (onde `XX` é de acordo com os critérios da regex):

```
3420201298      -> grupo 1: 2012
    ¯¯¯¯
34352020982012  -> grupo 1: 2012
          ¯¯¯¯
```

O `.*` irá buscar 0 ou mais caracteres à esquerda do grupo, ou seja, irá considerar a última sequência (`2012`) e não a primeira (`2020`).

**[REGEXR.COM](https://regexr.com/4d804)**

Comment: Ok, @Sam. Testei aqui e funcionou. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola `findall` retorna uma lista com todos os *matches*, por isso entendi que vc quisesse todos, e não somente o último. E a regex acima só pega a última ocorrência (se tiver três anos, por exemplo `text = '041202021982012'` - tem 2020, 2021 e 2012, vc só quer o último ou uma lista com os 3? Usando `.*` vc só obtém o último, usando um `for` como sugeri, vc tem uma lista com todos). Desculpe se entendi errado o que vc precisava, só queria tirar a dúvida mesmo...

Comment: Oi, @hkotsubo. Realmente a minha intenção era pegar os anos mais à direita, para depois pegar o última desta lista. Não sabia que poderia ser feito um algoritmo para pegar de cara o último, como esse acima.

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola É que da forma que foi perguntado, eu entendi que vc precisava pegar todos. Mas tudo bem, que bom que resolveu :-)

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) percorre a string da esquerda para a direita, e cada vez que encontra um *match*, a próxima busca começa depois do último trecho encontrado.

No caso, na string `0420202198`, depois de encontrado o `2020`, a procura começa a partir do terceiro `2` (o que começa o trecho `2198`), e por isso o `2021` não é encontrado.

Para fazer o que você precisa, uma opção é usar o [método `match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match), passando a posição em que a busca começará:

```
import re

text = '0420202198'
r = re.compile('20[1-2][0-9]')
years = []
# fazer buscas começando em todas as posições da string
for pos in range(0, len(text)):
    m = r.match(text, pos)
    if m:
        years.append(m.group())

print(years)
```

Neste caso não precisa incluir os parênteses na regex (eles servem para criar [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que são retornados por `findall`), pois o [método `group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group), quando chamado sem parâmetros, já retorna todo o trecho que foi encontrado.

Além disso não precisei usar *raw string* (o `r` antes das aspas). Esta sintaxe é útil quando a regex possui caracteres como o `\` (pois assim não preciso escrevê-lo como `\\`), mas neste caso não é necessário.

E também coloco os resultados em uma lista, para que o retorno seja o mesmo de `findall` (que retorna uma lista com os resultados).

A saída é:

> ['2020', '2021']

---

Como a sua regex necessariamente precisa de 4 dígitos para encontrar um *match*, eu poderia otimizar um pouco o *loop* e usar `range(0, len(text) - 3)` no `for` (assim eu evito iterar nas 3 últimas posições, pois eu sei que a partir daí não há mais caracteres suficientes para satisfazer a regex).

---

Se quiser, também pode usar a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052) (e *geralmente* mais sucinta, mas neste caso específico, não sei se é tanto assim):

```
import re

text = '0420202198'
r = re.compile('20[1-2][0-9]')    
years = [m.group() for pos in range(0, len(text) - 3) for m in [r.match(text, pos)] if m]
print(years)
```

Ou ainda:

```
years = [m.group() for m in (r.match(text, pos) for pos in range(0, len(text) - 3)) if m]
```

*Ambas as opções acima retiradas [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2436607)*.

Answer (score 1):

Tente mudar o variável `rg` para obter mais de uma ocorrência de um grupo de números

```
rg = r'20[1-2]\d+'
```

Pois desta forma sua regex busca por uma ou mais ocorrência de dígitos. A parte `\d` é equivalente a `"[0-9]"`

Comment: Isso não funciona, pois vai pegar **todos os dígitos** que existem depois do primeiro `20` em um único *match*, veja: https://ideone.com/QGS8ZW

Comment: É verdade, realmente não vai ajudar. Infelizmente não sei como ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Segue pattern para pegar somente o ano de 2012 que é o ano mais a direita como você disse

```
(?:.*?\K20[1-2]{1}[2-9]{1}){2}
```

[Clique aqui para ver o Exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/Rl7VQr/1)

Comment: Grato pela resposta, @Rodrigo. Mas eu gostaria de uma abordagem que atendesse o problema que indiquei, que é tratar os casos de anos que venham assim: 04**202021**98. Tipo, tem dois anos aí, mas do jeito que fiz só consigo pegar o 2020, não o 2021.

Comment: Novo Pattern: (?:(?<=20)20[1-2]{1}[0-9]{1})|(?:(20[1-2]{1}[2-9]{1}))

Comment: Creio que agora seja o que você quer: https://regex101.com/r/1metXT/1