# Adicionar uma string antes de determinada palavra utilizando Regex

Tags: python, regex

Estou lendo um arquivo com um código C e transformando em outro.

Gostaria de substituir o nome de uma variável que venha antes ou depois de um caractere de operação substituindo por "x" + nome_da_variável que vier antes do operador se for uma das variáveis de interesse, que no exemplo seguinte são `a`, `b` e `c`.

Este seria o código antes de aplicar a substituição.

```c
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    a=b+c;
}
```

E este seria o código após aplicar a substituição.

```c
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    xa=xb+xc;
}
```

Vale a pena observar que a variável `i` não é afetada pois ela não está na lista de variáveis a serem substituídas.
Estou utilizando o seguinte código Python com Regex.

```py
import regex as re
texto=[]
texto.append("int a,b,c;\n")
texto.append("{\n")
texto.append("\ta=b+c;\n")
var=[]
var.append("a")
var.append("b")
var.append("c")
texto.append("}\n")
for line in texto:
    for vari in var:
        line = re.sub(vari+"=","L1_structure."+vari+"=",line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub(vari+">","L1_structure."+vari+">",line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub(vari+"<","L1_structure."+vari+"<",line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub(vari+"\+","L1_structure."+vari+"+",line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub(vari+"\-","L1_structure."+vari+"-",line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub(vari+"\*","L1_structure."+vari+"*",line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub(vari+"\/","L1_structure."+vari+"/",line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub("="+vari,"L1_structure."+vari,line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub(">"+vari,"L1_structure."+vari,line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub("<"+vari,"L1_structure."+vari,line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub("\+"+vari,"L1_structure."+vari,line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub("\-"+vari,"L1_structure."+vari,line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub("\*"+vari,"L1_structure."+vari,line.rstrip())
        line = re.sub("\/"+vari,"L1_structure."+vari,line.rstrip())
    teste.append(line)
print(teste)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez regex não seja a melhor solução para o seu caso (por motivos que serão detalhados mais abaixo). De qualquer forma, **se você estiver lidando apenas com linhas simples como as que estão na pergunta**, dá para fazer o seguinte:

---

Você pode pegar a lista que tem os nomes das variáveis e criar uma única regex, usando [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) para as alternativas, e `\b` para demarcar a ["fronteira entre palavras"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (ou seja, apenas pegar o nome `a` quanto este estiver "solto" no texto, e não no meio de um nome maior, como `amarelo`, por exemplo):

```
import re

var = ['a', 'b', 'c']
# criar regex com os nomes das variáveis: \b(a|b|c)\b
r = re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(var)))
```

No caso, a regex resultante é `\b(a|b|c)\b` (os nomes `a` **ou** `b` **ou** `c`, demarcados por `\b` antes e depois - ou seja, evita casos em que as letras estão no meio de outras palavras, como "abacate").

Para nomes com apenas uma letra eu também poderia usar uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (ficando `\b[abc]\b`), mas usar alternância (com `|`) é mais garantido, pois também funciona para nomes com mais de uma letra (por exemplo, `\b(nome|idade)\b` buscaria por variáveis chamadas `nome` ou `idade`).

Depois é só fazer as substituições:

```
resultado = []
for line in texto:
    resultado.append(r.sub(r'L1_structure.\1', line))

print(''.join(resultado))
```

Na regex eu coloquei as opções entre parênteses, pois isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Com isso, o nome da variável é capturado e eu posso usá-lo na substituição, através da variável especial `\1` (já que é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex). Por isso a substituição feita é `L1_strucuture.` + o nome da variável que foi capturado.

O resultado é:

```
int L1_structure.a,L1_structure.b,L1_structure.c;
{
    L1_structure.a=L1_structure.b+L1_structure.c;
}
```

Se quiser, também pode usar a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052):

```
resultado = [r.sub(r'L1_structure.\1', line) for line in texto]
```

---

#### Atenção, isso não vai funcionar para qualquer código C

Como dito no início, a solução acima funciona para casos mais simples, como os que você colocou na pergunta.

Mas se você vai trabalhar com qualquer código C válido, aí fica bem mais complicado resolver somente com regex. Por exemplo, eu posso ter isso:

```c
int f() {
    int a = 1;
    ...
}

int main(void) {
    int a = f();
    ....
}
```

Repare que tenho duas variáveis `a`: uma dentro do `main` e outra dentro da função `f()`. Qual das duas deve ser mudada? Se você usar regex e processar linha a linha, ambas serão alteradas, mas nem sempre isso é o desejado - talvez você só queira mudar a variável `a` de um escopo específico, por exemplo, e nesse caso a regex não vai funcionar porque você precisaria analisar o contexto em que cada variável se encontra (e fazer isso com regex é bem complicado).

Há também o caso em que `a` pode ser o nome de uma função:

```c
int a(int x) {
    ...
    return whatever;
}

int f() {
    int a;
    ...
}

int main() {
    int result = a(2);
    ...
}
```

Como não confundir a função `a` com a variável `a` dentro da função `f`? Talvez se você especificar na regex que não pode ter `(` logo depois - mas ainda sim não detectará o caso em que função `a` é passada para um ponteiro de função:

```c
functionPtr = &a;
```

A menos que a regex também inclua um caso em que não haja um `&` antes, mas aí você não substitui os casos em que a variável é atribuída para um ponteiro - percebe que quanto mais casos surgem, mais complicado vai ficando?

---

Outro caso é se você tiver texto em uma string:

```c
printf("essa é a mensagem");
```

A regex teria que ignorar o `a` acima, pois ele está dentro de uma string. E fazer isso com regex [não é tão simples assim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4917932).

A mensagem acima também poderia estar em um comentário:

```c
/*
Esta é a mensagem dentro de um comentário.

int a; <- ignorar este também
*/
```

Novamente, os dois `a`'s acima devem ser ignorados, e fazer uma regex para detectar esse comentário [é bem complicada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42777793). E veja que neste caso não adianta avaliar linha por linha, a regex deve se extender por mais de uma linha e avaliar o texto como um todo. E você ainda teria que juntar essa regex com as anteriores - a que verifica se está dentro de uma string, a outra que verifica se é uma função, etc.

---

Talvez o seu caso (renomear variáveis) seja mais fácil de ser resolvido com uma IDE (a maioria possui funções que, com um ou poucos cliques, renomeiam variáveis facilmente). Ou, se quiser mesmo fazer programaticamente, procure por [*parsers* específicos](https://www.google.com/search?q=parse%20c%20code%20in%20python).

Answer (score 0):

Com regex dá para gravar a ocorrência com parênteses e usar o símbolo OR (o caractere `|`) para mais que uma palavra.

```
line = re.sub('(a|b|c)', "L1_structure." + r'\1', line.rstrip())
```

Comment: O problema é que palavras como amarelo ficariam L1_structure.amL1_structure.arelo .Alem disso, apesar de não estar claro no exemplo as variáveis que salvei não são conhecidas previamente por mim por isso estava usando um laço de repetição.

Answer (score 0):

No caso geral, processar C com expressões regulares pode ser complicado...
Para situações simples podemos tentar algo como

```
text = ''' i=b+c2; a="uma e a outra"; /* ignorando o a,b, */ '''

relev=['a','b','c2']

text =re.sub(r'"[^"]*"|/\*.*?\*/|\b(\w+)\b',
             lambda n: "x"+n[1] if n[1] in relev else n[0],
             text)
```

No final o valor de `text` é

```
i=xb+xc2; xa="uma e a outra"; /* ignorando o a,b, */
```

Para além dos identificadores,
para prova de conceito, estamos a contemplar strings simples e comentários uma única linha (o C completo precisaria de mais...).