# Remover somente strings de uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
Lista_1 = [10, 3, 6, 27, 'Maria']
Lista_2 = [37, 8, 45, 80, 'Jose']
Lista_3 = [43, 67, 99, 3.456, 'Pipoca']
Lista_4 = [432, 456, 333, 538, 'Bala']
```

#### Concatenando listas

```
Lista_Total = Lista_1 + Lista_2 + Lista_3 + Lista_4
[10, 3, 6, 27, 'Maria', 37, 8, 45, 80, 'Jose', 43, 67, 99, 3.456, 'Pipoca', 432, 456, 333, 538, 'Bala']
```

Como eu poderia remover somente as `str` dessa lista concatenada? Ou ainda ordenar por *type* e removê-las?

Answer (score 2):

Para saber se uma variável é uma string, use a [função `isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), como já explicado na [resposta do Fernando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/410835/112052). Aí basta percorrer a lista e desconsiderar os elementos que são strings:

```
Lista_Total = [ i for i in Lista_Total if not isinstance(i, str) ]
print(Lista_Total)
```

O resultado é a lista:

```
[10, 3, 6, 27, 37, 8, 45, 80, 43, 67, 99, 3.456, 432, 456, 333, 538]
```

Nesse caso, usei a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052).

Ela basicamente percorre a lista e cria outra lista, contendo somente os elementos que não são strings. No final, o resultado é atribuído para a variável `Lista_Total`.

Mas se quiser, pode fazer um `for` tradicional. O código abaixo é equivalente, gerando a mesma lista do código anterior:

```
lista_sem_strings = []
for i in Lista_Total:
    if not isinstance(i, str):
        lista_sem_strings.append(i)
```

Ao final do *loop*, `lista_sem_strings` será uma lista com todos os elementos que não são strings.

Answer (score 1):

Para verificar se uma variável é do tipo *string* você deve usar a função `isinstance()` e compará-la com `basestring` no caso do Python 2.x e `str` para Python 3. Exemplo com Python 2.7:

```
>>> isinstance('foo', basestring)
True
>>> isinstance(123, basestring)
False
```

Para eliminar elementos da lista você pode fazer de várias maneiras. Acho que a mais fácil de entender seria percorrer no sentido reverso e remover aquelas que `isinstance(x, basestring)` for `True`. Para o caso do Python 2.7:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(Lista_Total))):
    if isinstance(Lista_Total[i], basestring):
        del Lista_Total[i]
```

Se ainda assim você quiser ordená-la por tipo, basta ordená-la:

```
Lista_Total.sort()
```

O Python naturalmente compara inteiros com *strings* e coloca os números antes das *strings*.