# Como usar o join em uma lista de objetos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
class Pessoa:
      def __init__(self, nome, idade):
          self.nome = nome
          self.idade = idade

p1 = Pessoa('João', 15)  
p2 = Pessoa('Maria', 17)
lista_pessoas = [p1, p2]
```

Como usar o `join()` para imprimir a lista de nomes, ou a lista de idades sem ter que criar outra lista?

Comment: Você precisa de uma *string* apenas com todos os nomes ou todas as idades?

Comment: O que você quer fazer, não ta claro na pergunta

Answer (score 4):

Como você já tem uma lista de pessoas, pode usar a [função `map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
class Pessoa:
      def __init__(self, nome, idade):
          self.nome = nome
          self.idade = idade

p1 = Pessoa('João', 15)  
p2 = Pessoa('Maria', 17)
lista_pessoas = [p1, p2]
nomes = ', '.join(map(lambda p: p.nome, lista_pessoas))
print(nomes)
```

O primeiro parâmetro passado para `map` é um [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda): uma função que será aplicada a cada elemento da lista. No caso, o `lambda` recebe uma pessoa e retorna o seu respectivo nome, e faz isso para cada elemento da lista.

O detalhe é que a função `map` retorna um [iterador](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator). Ou seja, ela [não cria outra lista](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25653996).

Depois, usamos `join` para juntar os nomes, separando-os por `', '` (vírgula e um espaço). O resultado é:

```
João, Maria
```

---

Se quiser mostrar as idades, basta modificar o `lambda` para:

```
idades = ', '.join(map(lambda p: str(p.idade), lista_pessoas))
```

Mas como `idade` é um número, temos que usar [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) para convertê-lo para string. Ao final, a string `idades` terá o valor `15, 17`.

---

Outra alternativa é usar o que [foi sugerido nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/410900/como-usar-o-join-em-uma-lista-de-objetos#comment802398_410908):

```
nomes = ', '.join(p.nome for p in lista_pessoas)
```

Este código usa a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052). E além disso, ela cria um [*generator*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator#generator-expressions) (ou seja, ela também não cria outra lista).

Para as idades, ficaria:

```
idades = ', '.join(str(p.idade) for p in lista_pessoas)
```