# Trocar letra de uma frase em Python

Tags: python

Estou com um problema no meu código, a letra não está sendo substituída.

```py
def troca(quero_trocar, trocar_por, frase):
    for letra in frase:
        if(letra == quero_trocar):
            letra = trocar_por
    return frase
```

Tentei fazer assim mas também não funcionou:

```py
def troca(quero_trocar, trocar_por, frase):
    for letra in frase:
        if(letra == quero_trocar):
            frase[letra] = quero_trocar
    return frase
```

O erro foi:

> ```
> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
> ```

Comment: Você só atualizou a variável `letra` e não `frase`.

Comment: É exatamente nisso que estou em dúvida em como fazer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em Python, [string são imutáveis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str), então se você tentar fazer isso:

```
s = 'abc'
s[0] = 'x'
```

O resultado será um [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) (como de fato aconteceu com a sua segunda tentativa).

Nesse caso, o jeito é criar outra string com os caracteres trocados. Uma maneira de fazer é usar [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
def troca(quero_trocar, trocar_por, frase):
    return frase.replace(quero_trocar, trocar_por)

print(troca('a', 'b', 'abacate')) # bbbcbte
```

O detalhe é que `replace` pode trocar qualquer sequência de caracteres por outra, inclusive de tamanhos diferentes:

```
print(troca('aba', 'x', 'abacate')) # xcate
```

---

Se isso for um exercício e você "precisa" usar um *loop*, pode iterar pelos caracteres da string e ir construindo a outra string:

```
def troca(quero_trocar, trocar_por, frase):
    nova = []
    for c in frase:
        if c == quero_trocar:
            nova.append(trocar_por)
        else:
            nova.append(c)

    return ''.join(nova)

print(troca('a', 'x', 'abacate')) # xbxcxte
```

No caso, eu vou guardando os caracteres em uma lista, e no final eu junto tudo em uma única string, usando [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Mas se quiser, pode usar a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052):

```
def troca(quero_trocar, trocar_por, frase):
    return ''.join(trocar_por if c == quero_trocar else c for c in frase)
```

Comment: valeuuuu, ajudou muito! XD

Answer (score 0):

tente fazer o seguinte:

```
def troca(quero_trocar, trocar_por, frase):
    frase = frase.replace(quero_trocar, trocar_por, len(frase))
    return frase
```

No caso, o 'len(frase)' faz com que a função 'replace' percorra o máximo de caracteres possível na frase, assim ele trocará sempre todas as letras sem precisar entrar em um looping.

Ex:

```
quero_trocar = "a"
trocar_por = "b"
frase = "a aba da janela esta aberta"
frase = frase.replace(quero_trocar, trocar_por, len(frase))
```

O resultado será:

```
'b bbb db jbnelb estb bbertb'
```

Mas fácil e prático do que gerar um looping.

Comment: Obrigado, mas esse também da erro :c