# Obter de uma lista todos os índices cujo elemento é igual a determinado valor

Tags: python

Este é o meu código:

```
def procuras(lista,valor):
    dicionario = {}
    for valor in lista:
        if valor in dicionario:
            dicionario[valor] = [i for i, item in enumerate(lista) if item == valor]
        else:
            dicionario[valor] = lista.index(valor)
    return (dicionario[valor])
```

Corre desta forma:

```
 procuras([5,2,5,4,5,2,3,5], 5)
```

O resultado é sempre `8` mesmo que eu tente ver outro valor.
Precisava de obter:

```
procuras([1,2,1,4,5,2,3,1], 2)
```

`[1, 5]` - ou seja todos os índices onde ele aparece.

Caso não exista devia de me dar apenas: `[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não precisa criar um dicionário para guardar os índices. Basta percorrer a lista com [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), que você pode obter o índice e o respectivo elemento ao mesmo tempo:

```
def procuras(lista, valor):
    indices = []
    for indice, elemento in enumerate(lista):
        if valor == elemento:
            indices.append(indice)
    return indices
```

Assim, cada vez que o valor for encontrado na lista, eu adiciono o respectivo índice na lista de índices. Se o valor não for encontrado nenhuma vez, a lista retornada é vazia. Testando:

```
print(procuras([1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1], 2)) # [1, 5]
print(procuras([5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5], 5)) # [0, 2, 4, 7]
print(procuras([1, 2, 3], 5)) # []
```

---

Se quiser, também pode usar a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052).

```
def procuras(lista, valor):
    return [ indice for indice, elemento in enumerate(lista) if valor == elemento ]
```

O resultado é o mesmo do código anterior.

Comment: Obrigada funcionou :D