# Contar ocorrências de letra em uma frase de forma case insensitive

Tags: python

Eu queria conseguir deixar as variáveis do `input` como `lower`/`upper` para fazer a contagem de letras equivalentes na frase.

Só que a variável está como *iterable*, e quando eu adiciono o `.lower()` ela muda pra `str` e o código não funciona mais. Queria ajuda pra fazer isso de outra maneira.

Segue o código:

```
frase = input('Digite uma frase: ')
letra = input('Qual letra você deseja escanear? ')
c = 0
pos = []
for x in frase:
    if x == letra:
        c += 1
for n in enumerate(frase):
    if letra == n[1]:
        pos.append(n[0])
if c != 0:
    print(f'Existem {c} letra(s) "{letra}" na frase, nas posições {pos}.')
else:
    print(f'Não existe nenhum "{letra}" nesta frase.')
```

Comment: É isso que você está querendo fazer? `frase = input('Digite uma frase: ').upper()` e `letra = input('Qual letra você deseja escanear? ').upper()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não deu para entender o que você quis dizer com *"quando eu adiciono o `.lower()` ela muda pra `str` e o código não funciona mais"*, mas de qualquer forma, se quer transformar tudo em maiúscula (ou tudo em maiúscula) para poder fazer as comparações, uma opção seria fazer logo no `input`:

```
# transforma tudo em maiúscula
frase = input('Digite uma frase: ').upper()
letra = input('Qual letra você deseja escanear? ').upper()

# ou transforma tudo em minúscula
frase = input('Digite uma frase: ').lower()
letra = input('Qual letra você deseja escanear? ').lower()
```

Outro detalhe é que não precisa fazer dois *loops*. O [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) já retorna ao mesmo tempo a posição e o respectivo caractere, então bastaria fazer:

```
c = 0
pos = []
for posicao, caractere in enumerate(frase):
    if letra == caractere:
        pos.append(posicao)
        c += 1
```

Ou você pode guardar apenas a lista com as posições, sem precisar do contador. Se ao final do `for` a lista estiver vazia, é porque não encontrou nada:

```
pos = []
for posicao, caractere in enumerate(frase):
    if letra == caractere:
        pos.append(posicao)
if pos:
    print(f'Existem {len(pos)} letra(s) "{letra}" na frase, nas posições {pos}.')
else:
    print(f'Não existe nenhum "{letra}" nesta frase.')
```

O `if pos:` verifica se a lista não está vazia (aqui é aproveitado o fato de que [listas vazias são consideradas `False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)). Depois, para saber quantas vezes a letra ocorre, basta obter o tamanho da lista com [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).

---

Você ainda pode trocar o `for` acima por uma [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052).:

```
pos = [ posicao for posicao, caractere in enumerate(frase) if letra == caractere ]
```

---

Claro que você também poderia deixar a frase intacta e só converter para maiúscula (ou minúscula) na hora de comparar os caracteres:

```
frase = input('Digite uma frase: ')
letra = input('Qual letra você deseja escanear? ').lower()

pos = [ posicao for posicao, caractere in enumerate(frase) if letra == caractere.lower() ]
```

---

Por fim, se quer mesmo fazer uma comparação *case insensitive*, pode usar o [método `casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold). Ele é similar a [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower), porém um pouco mais "agressivo" e trata casos especiais, como por exemplo o [caractere `ß`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00df/index.htm), que quando transformado para maiúsculo, se torna "SS" (então `'ß'.upper().lower()` retorna "ss"):

```
print('ß'.lower() == 'SS'.lower()) # False
print('ß'.casefold() == 'SS'.casefold()) # True
```

Claro que para textos em português, não vai fazer tanta diferença assim usar `lower()` ou `casefold()`, mas enfim, fica registrada a dica.

Comment: Então, na hora de executar o programa, quando eu uso .lower() depois do input, ele para de reconhecer a variavel dentro do enumerate. Ele mostra uma mensagem dizendo algo como "esperou encontrar variável iterable, mas encontrou str". E o código dá erro. Já sobre não precisar usar o c, eu tinha feito primeiro essa parte e não voltei pra ajustar, mas valeu, vou corrigir. Mas de qualquer forma eu iria precisar fazer uma variável pra que eu pudesse dar uma opção caso não haja nenhuma letra, não é?

Comment: @punksn0g Vc testou os códigos que coloquei acima? Fiz do jeito que está aí e não deu esse erro. Só pra confirmar, é Python 3, certo? Acho que no 2 o `input` se comporta diferente, veja se está rodando na versão correta

Comment: @punksn0g Caso não haja nenhuma letra, ele cai no `else` e não precisa dessa variável (se cair no `else` você sabe que a letra ocorre zero vezes, o contador é redundante)

Comment: Vou testar aqui, brigadão. Qualquer coisa, volto a comentar.

Comment: @punksn0g Depois de testar, lembre-se também que se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.

Comment: Joia, pode deixar.Testei aqui e funcionou lindo. Muito legal o uso do list comprehension, pos isso que adoro python, é tudo muito mais simples!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode apenas utilizar o upper e o lower na letra de comparação e utilizar um único for para adicionar a posição e comparar conforme o código a seguir:

```
frase = input('Digite uma frase: ')
letra = input('Qual letra você deseja escanear? ')
c = 0
pos = []

for x in range(len(frase)):
    if frase[x] == letra.lower() or frase[x] == letra.upper():
        pos.append(x+1)
        c += 1

if c != 0:
    print(f'Existem {c} letra(s) "{letra}" na frase, nas posições {pos}.')
else:
    print(f'Não existe nenhum "{letra}" nesta frase.')
```

Fazendo isso você evita de modificar sua variável "frase" e evita que ela mude seu tipo.

Comment: Valeuu. Muito bom ver outros pontos de vista da mesma coisa.