# Como procurar texto parcial em uma lista de strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista

Eu tenho uma lista com vários elementos de texto, e eu gostaria de saber como eu posso encontrar um desses elementos procurando por uma parte do texto e não pelo texto exato.

Exemplo:

```
Lista = ['Jorge Henrique','Matheus Oliveira Santos','Sopa de batata doce','Algorítimos maravilhosos']
```

Agora imagine que eu quero encontrar o elemento que contém `'de bat'`
que no caso seria `'Sopa de batata doce'`.

Como eu posso fazer para encontrar dessa forma em Python e salvar em uma variável?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [operador `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) para verificar se uma string é uma substring de outra.

Só não ficou claro se você quer apenas uma das strings da lista (a primeira que encontrar, por exemplo), ou se quer todas que possuem a substring.

---

Se quiser apenas uma das strings, uma forma de fazer é:

```
elemento_encontrado = None
busca = 'de bat'
lista = ['Jorge Henrique', 'Matheus Oliveira Santos', 'Sopa de batata doce', 'Algorítimos maravilhosos']
for s in lista:
    if busca in s: # se "de bat" está contido na string
        elemento_encontrado = s
        break

if elemento_encontrado:
    print(elemento_encontrado) # Sopa de batata doce
```

Neste caso, eu paro assim que encontrar algum caso válido (o uso do `break` interrompe o *loop*, ou seja, ele para no primeiro caso que encontrar e nem olha para o restante). Depois eu só verifico se foi realmente encontrado alguma string e a imprimo.

Você ainda pode usar um bloco `else` no `for`, que é chamado caso ele não seja interrompido pelo `break` (ou seja, se nenhum caso for encontrado):

```
for s in lista:
    if busca in s: # se "de bat" está contido na string
        elemento_encontrado = s
        break
else:
    print('Nenhum elemento encontrado')
```

---

Agora se quiser **todas** as strings que contém a substring desejada, pode usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) para retornar uma lista com todos os casos:

```
busca = 'a'
lista = ['Jorge Henrique', 'Matheus Oliveira Santos', 'Sopa de batata doce', 'Algorítimos maravilhosos']
# obtém uma lista com todas as strings que contém "a"
encontrados = [ s for s in lista if busca in s ]
print(encontrados) # ['Matheus Oliveira Santos', 'Sopa de batata doce', 'Algorítimos maravilhosos']
```

A linha `encontrados = [ s for s in lista if busca in s ]` é a *list comprehension*, e é equivalente ao `for` abaixo:

```
encontrados = []
for s in lista:
    if busca in s:
        encontrados.append(s)
```

Mas a *list comprehension* é mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052).

Comment: muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema aqui

Answer (score 2):

Ola,

Existem os Operadores de associação do Python `in` e `not in`, que são usados ​​para testar se uma sequência é apresentada em um objeto. Você pode checar mais sobre eles [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in)

Para sua solução você pode fazer o seguinte

```
resultado = [valor for valor in lista if 'de bat'  in valor ]
```