# Somar os elementos negativos de uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Quero somar somente os elementos negativos de uma lista em Python.
O código que eu pensei inicialmente foi:

```
lista = [12, -2, 4, 8, 29, 45, 78, 36, -17, 2, 12, 8, 3, 3, -52]

for n in lista:
    if n < 0:
    soma_dos_negativos = sum(n)
print('A soma dos elementos negativos é igual a {}'.format(soma_dos_negativos))
```

Mas o código nem chega a funcionar.

Answer (score 4):

Um dos motivos do código não funcionar é a falta de identação após o `if`:

```
if n < 0:
soma_dos_negativos = sum(n)
```

Isso causa um [`IndentationError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndentationError). Para que o código seja executado somente se `n` for negativo, tem que identar:

```
if n < 0:
    soma_dos_negativos = sum(n)
```

**Mas só isso não resolve**, pois segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), `sum` deve receber um iterável (ou seja, uma lista, uma tupla, etc, e ele retorna a soma dos elementos deste iterável). Só que você está passando um número (a cada iteração do `for`, a variável `n` assume um dos valores da lista, que no caso só tem números), e números não são iteráveis (por isso esse código [também dá erro](https://ideone.com/thSfjf)).

---

Enfim, não faz sentido usar `sum` com um número (já que `sum` serve para retornar a soma dos elementos de um iterável). E mesmo se fizesse sentido, seu código está sobrescrevendo o valor de `soma_dos_negativos` a cada iteração. Em vez disso, você deve somar o valor de cada número a esta variável (não esquecendo de inicializá-la com zero):

```
lista = [12, -2, 4, 8, 29, 45, 78, 36, -17, 2, 12, 8, 3, 3, -52]
soma_dos_negativos = 0
for n in lista:
    if n < 0:
        soma_dos_negativos += n # some o valor de n ao total já computado
print('A soma dos elementos negativos é igual a {}'.format(soma_dos_negativos))
```

Mas se quiser, pode trocar o `for` por uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions), mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052):

```
lista = [12, -2, 4, 8, 29, 45, 78, 36, -17, 2, 12, 8, 3, 3, -52]
soma_dos_negativos = sum(n for n in lista if n < 0)
print('A soma dos elementos negativos é igual a {}'.format(soma_dos_negativos))
```

Agora sim posso usar `sum`, pois a *generator expression* é iterável. No caso, ela pega somente os números negativos da lista, e `sum` retorna a soma destes.

Outra opção é usar [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) para filtrar os elementos que você quer, e em seguida passar o resultado para `sum`:

```
soma_dos_negativos = sum(filter(lambda n: n < 0, lista))
```

O `filter` recebe um [*lambda*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) que verifica se o número é negativo, filtrando assim os números negativos da lista, que por sua vez são passados para `sum`, que retorna a soma destes.

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas se estiver usando Python >= 3.6, pode usar [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) para exibir a mensagem:

```
print(f'A soma dos elementos negativos é igual a {soma_dos_negativos}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para filtrar os elementos da lista com valores menores que zero para então somá-los com a função [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) veja só:

```
lista = [12, -2, 4, 8, 29, 45, 78, 36, -17, 2, 12, 8, 3, 3, -52]

soma_dos_negativos = sum([i for i in lista if i < 0])

print('A soma dos elementos negativos é igual a {}'.format(soma_dos_negativos))
```

Saída:

```
A soma dos elementos negativos é igual a -71
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/InsecureDelectableStack)

Answer (score 1):

Posso sugerir:

```
lista = [12, -2, 4, 8, 29, 45, 78, 36, -17, 2, 12, 8, 3, 3, -52]

print (sum(filter(lambda x: x < 0, lista)))
```

Answer (score -4):

```
l=[12, -2, 4, 8, 29, 45, 78, 36, -17, 2, 12, 8, 3, 3, -52]
soma=0

for n in l:

  n=int(n)

  if n<0:

    soma=soma+n

print(soma)
```