# Como verificar se ocorreu ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer um programa em Python que execute uma equação de segundo grau: e delta é menor do que zero (não exite raiz); se é igual a zero (só tem uma raiz); se é maior que zero (existem duas raízes).

Porém meu programa não funciona quando delta é menor do que zero, eu gostaria de pegar o tipo de erro e executar no "if" assim: `if delta == ValueError:`, só que não consegui fazer isso, tem uma outra alternativa?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: Vi que vc marcou minha resposta como correta e depois desmarcou. Faltou alguma coisa, tem algo que não entendeu? Se foi isso me avise que posso editá-la acrescentando o que faltou, se for o caso

Comment: Não, muito obrigado, desculpe por eu demorar pra responder, mas muito obrigado mesmo, eu não sabia que dava erro por ser valor negativo (risos).

Comment: Bom, se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Comment: Desculpe por ter tirado print do código, sou novo no Stack, na próxima coloco como texto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem como fazer `if delta == ValueError` porque [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) é uma exceção que é lançada por [`math.sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sqrt) quando você passa um valor negativo: [exceção](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) é diferente de valor retornado, o `ValueError` (e qualquer outra exceção) desvia o fluxo do programa; a exceção **não** é um valor que é retornado e atribuído para variável `delta`. Nesse caso você [deve usar um bloco `try`/`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) para capturar a exceção. Seria algo assim:

```
try:
    VALOR1 = (-BX + math.sqrt(DELTA)) / (2* AX2)
except ValueError: # se delta é negativo, math.sqrt lança um ValueError
    print('erro, não foi possível calcular a raiz de delta')
```

Se delta é negativo, `math.sqrt` lança um `ValueError`, e o código cai dentro do bloco `except`.

---

**Mas na verdade nada disso é necessário**. Por que você não testa se o delta é negativo **antes** de calcular a raiz quadrada dele? Pois se ele for negativo, não há raízes reais e aí nem faz sentido tentar calculá-las:

```
from math import sqrt

a = float(input("Digite o valor de A: "))
b = float(input("Digite o valor de B: "))
c = float(input("Digite o valor de c: "))

delta = b ** 2 - (4 * a * c)
if delta < 0:
    print("A raiz não existe")
elif delta == 0:
    print("a única raiz é : ", -b / (2 * a))
else: # se chegou aqui é porque delta é positivo
    raiz_delta = sqrt(delta) # aqui sim posso calcular a raiz quadrada sem problema
    print("o valor da primeira raiz é:  ", (-b + raiz_delta) / (2 * a))
    print("o valor da segunda raiz é:  ", (-b - raiz_delta) / (2 * a))
```

Se o delta é negativo, não precisa calcular a raiz quadrada, basta imprimir a mensagem que não há raízes e pronto. Repare que aqui não precisa fazer nenhum cálculo, já que como não há raízes, então não há o que calcular. Por isso não faz sentido tentar calcular as raízes antes de saber se o delta é negativo. Assim você não faz coisas à toa e ainda evita que o `ValueError` ocorra, não precisando nem lidar com o mesmo.

Se o delta for zero, também não precisa calcular a raiz quadrada, pois ela será zero e não fará diferença no cálculo: fazer `-b + sqrt(delta)` ou `-b - sqrt(delta)`, sendo que a `sqrt(0)` é zero, é o mesmo que simplesmente usar o valor de `-b`, por isso eu fiz apenas `-b / (2 * a)` (note também que não precisa criar duas variáveis antes, pois nesse caso elas terão mesmo valor).

Somente se o delta for positivo, aí sim você calcula a raiz quadrada dele. Eu não criei as variáveis `VALOR1` e `VALOR2` porque você só quer imprimir o resultado uma vez e nada mais, mas caso queira usar seus valores para fazer outras coisas depois, aí pode guardá-los em variáveis.

---

Se quiser que tenha raízes complexas (ou seja, que também funcione se o delta for negativo), basta trocar o módulo `math` por [`cmath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html):

```
from cmath import sqrt

a = float(input("Digite o valor de A: "))
b = float(input("Digite o valor de B: "))
c = float(input("Digite o valor de c: "))

delta = b ** 2 - (4 * a * c)
if delta == 0:
    print("a única raiz é : ", -b / (2 * a))
else:
    raiz_delta = sqrt(delta) # aqui sim posso calcular a raiz quadrada sem problema
    print("o valor da primeira raiz é:  ", (-b + raiz_delta) / (2 * a))
    print("o valor da segunda raiz é:  ", (-b - raiz_delta) / (2 * a))
```

Neste caso, só tratei o caso do delta ser zero, pois aí não precisa calcular a raiz. Para os demais casos, o módulo `cmath` já trata corretamente.

---

<sup>*A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/437854/112052) cria uma função cujo resultado não é usado para nada (repare que ela chama a função, mas o resultado não é guardado em nenhum lugar), e depois ela ainda calcula as raízes mesmo se o delta for negativo (ou seja, mesmo quando não precisa). Pode até "funcionar" (mostrar as mensagens corretas para cada caso), mas faz coisas desnecessárias e complica à toa algo que é bem simples de resolver fazendo as coisas na ordem certa, como indicado acima.*</sup>

Comment: Aquilo que o maniero fala sempre: "Funcionar é diferente de estar correto" , você tem razão, não é necessário calcular a raíz quando o deltar for negativo e zero, não editarei minha resposta para ficar de contra ponto com a sua e ver que esta é mais correta que aquela. +1

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação do Python 3.x este erro [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) é causado *Gerado quando uma operação ou função recebe um argumento que tem o tipo certo, mas um valor inadequado*. ( Traduzido via google translate).

No seu caso especifico este erro é por que você está trabalhando a função `math.sqrt` com número negativo, para contornar este problema você precisa definir uma função, conforme abaixo:

```
import math
def raiz_quadrada(DELTA):
        return math.sqrt(-DELTA) 
AX2 = float(input("Digite o valor de A: "))
BX = float(input("Digite o valor de B: "))
C = float(input("Digite o valor de c: "))

DELTA = BX**2 - (4 * AX2 * C)
if DELTA < 0:
    raiz_quadrada(DELTA)


VALOR1 = (-BX + DELTA) / (2* AX2)
VALOR2 = (-BX - DELTA) / (2* AX2)

if DELTA == 0:
        print("a única raiz é : ", valor1)
else: 
    if DELTA < 0:
        print("A raiz não existe")
    else:
        print("o valor da primeira raiz é:  ", VALOR1)
        print("o valor da segunda raiz é:  ", VALOR2)
```

Procurando uma solução mais [pythonica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192343/o-que-%C3%A9-c%C3%B3digo-pyth%C3%B4nico), você pode usar a biblioteca [cmath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html), *que trabalha com funções matemáticas para números complexos*,ou seja, **aceita números negativos**, com isto somente altere `math.sqrt` para `cmath.sqrt`, sendo assim seu código ficará:

```
...
DELTA = BX**2 - 4 * AX2 * C
VALOR1 = (-BX + cmath.sqrt(DELTA)) / (2* AX2)
VALOR2 = (-BX - cmath.sqrt(DELTA)) / (2* AX2)
...
```

Comment: Valeu, por ter me dado a dica de usar o cmath, muito obrigado.