# Traceback (most recent call last) math domain error

Tags: python

```
import math

a = float(input("Digite 'a': "))
b = float(input("Digite 'b': "))
c = float(input("Digite 'c': "))

delta = b**2 - (4*a*c)

if(delta < 0):
  print("Raízes complexas!")
elif(delta == 0):
  print("2 raízes reais iguais!")
else:
  print("2 raízes reais diferentes!")

x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(delta))/2*a
x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(delta))/2*a

print("As raízes são:", x1, " e ", x2)
```

---

```
Digite 'a': 1
Digite 'b': 1
Digite 'c': 1
Raízes complexas!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-51bd2b58d810> in <module>()
     14   print("2 raízes reais diferentes!")
     15 
---> 16 x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(delta))/2*a
     17 x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(delta))/2*a
     18 

ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: Mas se possui raízes complexas por qual motivo você tenta calcula-las como se fossem reais?

Comment: Na realidade as raízes são: (-0.500000 - 0.866025*i) e (-0.500000 + 0.866025*i), onde i é a raiz quadrada de (-1).

Comment: O que eu estou tentando entender é quais são os fatores que causaram os 'ValueError', o que está errado no tocante a programação, não à matemática.

Comment: Sem ver o código é difícil adivinhar (seria bom [edit] a pergunta e adicioná-lo), mas *assumindo* que o delta foi calculado corretamente, então ele é negativo e `math.sqrt` lança um `ValueError` quando o número é negativo. Neste caso você deve usar o módulo cmath: https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#module-cmath - E sem querer ser chato mas já sendo, perceba que o erro está relacionado à programação **e também** à matemática :-)

Comment: Bom, ou vc usa o módulo `cmath`, que consegue trabalhar com números complexos (incluindo raiz quadrada de números negativos), ou então só calcule a raiz de delta se o delta for positivo, como foi feito por exemplo aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/437857/112052

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância, sou extremamente 'noob' na programação. Como eu uso o cmath?

Comment: Da mesma forma que usou math: `import cmath` e depois `cmath.sqrt` (basicamente, onde tem "math", troque por "cmath")

Comment: E onde está `math.sqrt(delta)` use `cmath.sqrt(delta)`

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu imaginei, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O erro acontece por que o seu programa tenta conseguir a raiz quadrada de um número negativo, o que não é permitido pela função math.sqrt. Para pegar os valores complexos você terá que usar a biblioteca `cmath`:

```
import cmath

a = float(input("Digite 'a': "))
b = float(input("Digite 'b': "))
c = float(input("Digite 'c': "))

delta = b**2 - (4*a*c)

if(delta < 0):
  print("Raízes complexas!")
elif(delta == 0):
  print("2 raízes reais iguais!")
else:
  print("2 raízes reais diferentes!")

x1 = (-b + cmath.sqrt(delta))/2*a
x2 = (-b - cmath.sqrt(delta))/2*a

print("As raízes são:", x1, " e ", x2)
```