# Como remover um objeto de uma lista durante uma iteração sobre a própria lista

Tags: python, lista

Preciso remover um item de uma lista durante uma iteração sobre a própria lista.

O motivo para remover durante o loop é que se esse item permanecer pode acabar disparando outros gatilhos dentro do loop o que levaria a um resultado falso já que os testes que faço sobre o objeto dentro da lista devem ser sequenciais.

Qual é a maneira mais apropriada (eficiente/idiomática) de se remover um objeto de uma lista quando iterando sobre a mesma?

```
lista=[] # Lista de obejos ativos.
class teste():
    ent = 0
    sai = 0

def alt(i):
    t = teste()
    t.ent = i
    t.sai = 2*i
    lista.append(t)
    print(t.ent,t.sai)

def objetos_ativos(x):
    print('O objeto ({} , {}) está ativo: '.format(x.ent, x.sai))

for i in range(5):
    alt(i)
print('')
#  Se usar ' lista.copy() ' para fazer a iteração sobre a  lista,  
#    x irá acionar a 'def objetos_ativos' e printar (20 , 4) como objeto ativo.
for x in (lista.copy()):
    # Trecho com problema
    if x.sai==4: # Se objeto 'x' falhar nesse teste ele é desativado imediatamente.
        lista.remove(x)
    #
    x.ent = x.ent * 10
    # Segundo teste que se o objeto foi desativado não deve participar.
    if x.ent >= 1:
        objetos_ativos(x)

for x in lista:
    print(x.ent, x.sai)
```

A entrada é:

```
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8
```

E eu esperava a saída como:

```
0 0
10 2
30 6
40 8
```

Mas em vez disso retorna:

```
0 0
10 2
3 6
40 8
```

Comment: tem que usar a palavra ```continue``` para que passe para a seguinte iteração ou para que saia do loop caso não haja mais nenhuma, dessa forma não vai tentar fazer "x.ent = x.ent * 10" dando erro, eu suponho.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @André isto junto com a solução do hkotsubo era exatamente o que eu procurava.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para entender o que acontece, vamos modificar um pouco o seu *loop*:

```
for i, x in enumerate(lista):
    print(f'Pegando elemento {i} = {x.ent}, {x.sai}')
    if x.sai == 4:
        lista.remove(x)
    x.ent = x.ent * 10
```

Eu uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para iterar pela lista obtendo o índice e seu respectivo elemento. A saída é:

```
Pegando elemento 0 = 0, 0
Pegando elemento 1 = 1, 2
Pegando elemento 2 = 2, 4
Pegando elemento 3 = 4, 8
```

Para entender a saída acima: a lista originalmente tem 5 elementos:

```
[ (0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8) ]
```

Até o elemento no índice 2 (ou seja, `(2, 4)`), tudo ocorre normalmente. Mas aí você remove esse elemento da lista, então a lista passa a ser:

```
[ (0, 0), (1, 2), (3, 6), (4, 8) ]
```

E na próxima iteração do `for`, ele tenta pegar o índice 3, que agora corresponde ao elemento `(4, 8)` (ou seja, o `(3, 6)` foi "pulado").

Esse é o problema de remover itens de uma lista enquanto está iterando nela.

---

Uma alternativa é você construir outra lista contendo somente os elementos que quer:

```
class teste:
    def __init__(self, ent=0, sai=0):
        self.ent = ent
        self.sai = sai

# cria a lista...

outra_lista = [ teste(x.ent * 10, x.sai) for x in lista if x.sai != 4 ]
for x in outra_lista:
    print(x.ent, x.sai)
```

Também adicionei um construtor na classe `teste`, assim eu consigo criá-la já passandos os valores de `ent` e `sai`. E para construir a nova lista, usei a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052) (mas nada impede de você fazer um *loop* normal e ir populando a outra lista).

O código acima não modifica a lista original, mas se quiser alterá-la diretamente, uma alternativa é fazer:

```
lista[:] = ( teste(x.ent * 10, x.sai) for x in lista if x.sai != 4 )
```

O "truque" é o `[:]`, que cria um [*slice*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) (um "pedaço" da lista, que no caso é a lista inteira). Assim, a lista é substituída pelos novos valores.

---

[A documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) ainda cita outra alternativa, que é iterar em uma cópia da lista:

```
for x in lista.copy():
    if x.sai == 4:
        lista.remove(x)
    x.ent = x.ent * 10
```

Assim, a remoção de elementos da lista não interfere na iteração, já que esta é feita uma cópia.

---

Sobre o problema de chamar a função `objetos_ativos`, bastaria não chamá-la caso ele tenha sido removido (ou, no caso, só chamar se o elemento não for removido). Então um bloco `else` já resolveria:

```
for x in lista.copy():
    if x.sai == 4:
        lista.remove(x)
    else:
        x.ent = x.ent * 10
        if x.ent >= 1:
            objetos_ativos(x)
```

Comment: Olá hkotsubo, muito obrigado pela explicação, muito didática e instrutiva. Consegui entender o porque do erro e como corrigir para esse caso. Mas como disse esse código é um exemplo. Não sei se fui claro o suficiente na explicação, mas no caso real o loop continua e outros teste são feitos sobre o objeto 'x' o que pode fazer com que 'x' chame outras funções dentro loop o que não deveria acontecer porque 'x' já não está mais ativo após falhar no teste 'x.sai == 4'.

Comment: @ThalesAlmeida Nesse caso eu sugiro que vc [**edite a pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/438696/edit) e coloque um exemplo mais próximo do caso real, assim eu posso atualizar a resposta também

Comment: @ThalesAlmeida Atualizei a resposta (espero ter entendido o problema)

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado. Testei agora também a solução com o "continue" que o André sugeriu + a copia da lista que você sugeriu e deu certo também. Muito obrigado pelas explicações.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Thales.

Ao que parece o erro consiste em remover o objeto da lista que está servindo de parâmetro para a iteração.

Uma solução seria guardar esse parâmetro em uma variável temporária e, após sua finalização, utilizar esse parâmeto para remover o objeto da lista, como a seguir:

```
lista=[]
class teste():
    ent = 0
    sai = 0

def alt(i):
    t = teste()
    t.ent = i
    t.sai = 2*i
    lista.append(t)
    print(t.ent,t.sai)


for i in range(5):
    alt(i)
print('')

for x in lista:
    x.ent = x.ent * 10
    if x.sai == 4:
        temp = x
lista.remove(temp)

for x in lista:
    print(x.ent, x.sai)
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços.

Comment: Olá João, obrigado pela resposta. Editei minha pergunta para explicar melhor meu problema. No caso real eu preciso que após x ser removido da lista ele não continue mais a interagir com o código do loop e chamar outras funções.