# Fazer a soma dos n termos ímpares ,usando Loop for ,sem usar lista, funções permitidas:input,int,print e range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n =(int(input("Digite o número de termos:")))

for i in range(n+n):
    if i%2>0:
      print(i)     

#Não sei como prosseguir depois,como pego esses valores e somo eles
```

Comment: O for deve ser montado da seguinte forma <code>for i in range(1, n + 1)</code>. Além disso deve ser implementado um contador.

Answer (score 6):

Um detalhe: no título é dito que você quer somar os "**n termos ímpares**", e no código tem a mensagem `"Digite o número de termos"`. Isso quer dizer que `n` é a **quantidade** de números ímpares, certo?

Por exemplo, se `n` for `5`, você quer somar todos os ímpares de 1 a 5 (ou seja, 1 + 3 + 5), ou quer somar os 5 primeiros números ímpares (ou seja, 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9)? As outras respostas entenderam que é a primeira opção...

De qualquer forma, vamos ver uma solução para cada:

---

## Somar os ímpares de 1 a `n`

Se for isso, há várias opções. Pode ser com um loop simples:

```
n = int(input("Digite o número de termos:"))
soma = 0
for i in range(1, n + 1, 2):
    soma += i
print(soma) # 9 (1 + 3 + 5)
```

Repare que eu uso o terceiro parâmetro do [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), que é o *step*, ou seja, o incremento que é somado a cada elemento para gerar o próximo. Se o `range` começa em `1` e eu só quero os números ímpares, posso pular de 2 em 2. Não há necessidade **nenhuma** de avançar de 1 em 1 e ir testando se o número é par ou ímpar (a menos que seja um exercício que "*exija*" que se faça isso).

Repare também que o `range` termina em `n + 1`, pois o último número não é incluso (ou seja, se eu colocar apenas `n`, o próprio `n` não seria somado).

Outra forma de fazer é usar [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), juntamente com uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052):

```
soma = sum(i for i in range(1, n + 1, 2))
print(soma)
```

Se bem que `sum` recebe como parâmetro um iterável, e *ranges* são iteráveis, então dá para simplificar ainda mais:

```
soma = sum(range(1, n + 1, 2))
print(soma)
```

---

## Somar os `n` primeiros números ímpares

Se quando `n` for, por exemplo, igual a `5`, e o objetivo é somar os 5 primeiros números ímpares (ou seja, 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9), aí fica assim:

```
soma = 0
impar = 1
for i in range(n):
    soma += impar
    impar += 2
print(soma) # 25 (1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9)
```

O `range(n)` serve para controlar a quantidade de números ímpares, e o número ímpar começa em 1 e vai sendo incrementado de 2 em 2.

O `for` acima também pode ser mais sucinto:

```
soma, impar = 0, 1
for i in range(n):
    soma, impar = soma + impar, impar + 2
```

Se bem que o enésimo número ímpar é igual a `2n - 1`, então bastaria usar soluções similares ao primeiro caso, mas agora usando um `range` até `2n`:

```
soma = 0
for i in range(1, 2 * n, 2):
    soma += i
print(soma)

# ou
soma = sum(range(1, 2 * n, 2))
print(soma)
```

---

Mas na verdade esse problema se resume à soma de uma PA ([progressão aritmética](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)), e nesse caso existe uma fórmula pronta para a soma dos N primeiros termos:

```
(a1 + an) * n / 2
```

- `a1` é o primeiro termo (no nosso caso, é 1)
- `an` é o enésimo termo, que por sua vez é igual a `a1 + (n - 1) * r` (e `r` é a razão, que no nosso caso é 2 - a diferença entre cada termo da PA)

Sendo assim, basta aplicar a fórmula:

```
n = int(input("Digite o número de termos:"))

soma = (1 + 1 + (n - 1) * 2) * n / 2
```

---

Mas repare que se você simplificar a fórmula acima com esses valores específicos (`a1=1` e `r=2`), vai chegar à conclusão de que a soma dos `n` primeiros números ímpares [é igual a `n` ao quadrado](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-n-odd-numbers), então um jeito mais sucinto ainda é:

```
soma = n * n

# ou
soma = n ** 2
```

---

Obs: a fórmula da PA também pode ser aplicada para o primeiro caso (somar números ímpares de 1 a `n`). Mas nesse caso `n` é o enésimo termo, e a quantidade de termos deve ser calculada:

```
# calcule a quantidade de termos
qtd = (1 + n) // 2

# use a fórmula da soma da PA
soma = (1 + n) * qtd / 2

# ou, como é a soma dos primeiros "qtd" ímpares, use a "fórmula simplificada"
soma = qtd ** 2
```

---

Mas se for um exercício que "exige" que se use um `for` de 1 em 1 e também o operador `%`, aí a solução é:

```
# soma dos ímpares de 1 a n
soma = 0
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        soma += i
print(soma)

# soma dos n primeiros ímpares
soma = 0
for i in range(1, 2 * n):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        soma += i
print(soma)
```

Answer (score 4):

Existe alguns problemas, como o seu `range` que está aumentando (dobrando) a quantidade de termos:

```
range(n+n)
```

Para pegar os valores, basta acessar a variável do loop, você já faz isso, mas apenas imprime o conteúdo dela:

```
print(i)
```

---

Para somar os termos, você vai precisar de uma outra variável, vamos criar ela com o valor de zero e chamar ela de soma, pra ficar bem evidente seu intuito:

```
soma = 0
```

No `for`, vamos utilizar ele de 1 até o termo:

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
```

Agora dentro do `for`, vamos somar o valor na variável `soma` sempre que o mesmo for ímpar;

```
if i%2>0:
  soma += i
```

E por fim, apenas imprimimos o valor da variável `soma`:

```
print(soma)
```

---

Juntando tudo, o código ficará da seguinte forma:

```
n = int(input("Digite o número de termos:"))
soma = 0

for i in range(1, n+1):
  if i%2 > 0:
    soma += i

print(soma)
```

---

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/RashFortunateLevels

Answer (score 4):

Cá vai a solução. Não percebi para que estás a somar **n + n**?

```
n =(int(input("Digite o número de termos:")))

result = 0

for i in range(n):
  if not i % 2 == 0:
    result += i


print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesta questão você tem que prestar atenção em duas coisas.

1ª Coisa:

Definir uma variável acumuladora (variável que armazenará o cálculo realizado em cada iteração do "for"). Variável que vou chamar de `"x"`.

2ª Coisa:

Estruturar corretamente o for.

Se você pretende utilizar o laço de repetição `"for"`, iterando sobre um range, você tem que definir os limites deste range.
Neste caso, o `for` ficaria da forma...

```
for c in range(1, n + 1):
```

...onde `"1"` seria o limite inferior e `"n + 1"` o limite superior.

Com estas duas situações em mente, desenvolvi o seguinte algoritmo abaixo.

```
# Capturando e tratando o valor inserido no input.
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Digite o número de termos: '))
        if n <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else: 
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

# Realizando os cálculos e exibindo o resultado:
x = 0
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    if c % 2 != 0:
        x += c
print(f'O resultado é: {x}')
```

Observe o funcionamento do código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/join/rarktbcs-solkarped)

Observe também que este algoritmo realiza um tratamento dos valores capturados pelo input.

Comment: Só uma dica: não precisa colocar um `while` dentro do outro. O `while` externo já garante a repetição, basta verificar as condições e só chamar o `break` se o número for válido, assim: https://ideone.com/QoGGSr (outra vantagem é não ter que repetir a chamada do `input`)

Comment: A função do <code>while</code> interno é restringir números inteiros menores que <code>"0"</code>. Note que se você digitar um valor <code>menor que "0"</code> o algoritmo não irá avançar. O algorimto só irá avançar se o valor for maior do que <code>"0"</code> por esta razão ha necessidade de implementar este segundo <code>"while"</code>.

Comment: Vc viu o link que passei? https://ideone.com/QoGGSr - ele faz a mesma coisa, sem precisar do `while` interno :-)

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Sim, entendi sua colocação. Eu acho que a única diferença foi apenas no tipo de estrutura. Você utilizou o "if" e eu um segundo "while". Obrigado pela dica. Abraço!

Comment: Bom, outra diferença, como eu já disse, é que assim não precisa repetir a chamada de `input` duas vezes - pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas se vc quiser mudar a mensagem, por exemplo, teria que mudar em 2 lugares, já da forma que fiz, basta mudar em um único lugar. Evitar repetição desnecessária é algo que pode ajudar muito na manutenção do código (em código pequeno talvez não faça tanta diferença, mas conforme o código aumenta, esses pequenos detalhes ajudam muito)

Comment: Ok. Os seus argumentos de fato procedem. Em um código grande a manutenção ficaria inviável. Vou retificar o código.