# Quantas vezes o maior número foi lido?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com o seguinte problema: o usuário entra com a quantidade de números a serem lidos, posteriormente quero que o maior entre essa quantidade 'X' de números seja exibida e também quantas vezes esse maior valor ocorreu.

Código até agora:

```
i = 0
lista_num = []

qtd_num = int(input('Entre com a quantidade de números a serem lidos: '))

while i < qtd_num:
    num = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    i += 1
    lista_num.append(num)

print(f'O maior valor é: {max(lista_num)}')
```

Como eu poderia implementar o contador de ocorrência do maior valor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), que retorna a quantidade de vezes que o elemento ocorre na lista:

```
lista_num = ...
maior = max(lista_num)
print(f'O maior valor é {maior} e ele ocorre {lista_num.count(maior)} vezes')
```

Outra opção é usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

lista_num = ...
maior = max(lista_num)
c = Counter(lista_num)
print(f'O maior valor é {maior} e ele ocorre {c[maior]} vezes')
```

A diferença é que `Counter` é um dicionário contendo a quantidade de ocorrências de todos os elementos da lista, enquanto `lista.count()` retorna apenas a quantidade de um único elemento.

---

Não diretamente relacionado ao problema, mas para ler os números não precisa dessa variável `i`, basta usar um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
lista_num = []
for _ in range(qtd_num):
    lista_num.append(int(input('Digite um número: ')))
```

E se quiser, também pode usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052):

```
lista_num = [ int(input('Digite um número: ')) for _ in range(qtd_num) ]
```

Você também poderia validar se o que foi digitado é de fato um número, capturando o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) (que ocorre caso [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) não receba uma string que possa ser convertida em número):

```
def ler_numero(msg):
    while True: # enquanto não digitar um número, pede que digite novamente
        try:
            return int(input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            print('Você não digitou um número')

qtd_num = ler_numero('Entre com a quantidade de números a serem lidos: ')
lista_num = [ ler_numero('Digite um número: ') for _ in range(qtd_num) ]
```

---

Obs: os códigos acima assumem que você tem uma lista e a partir dela quer obter o maior número e a quantidade de ocorrências do mesmo.

Mas se você só quer ler uma certa quantidade de números e no final obter essas informações, nem precisa da lista. Você pode usar o mesmo *loop* que lê os números para já ir vendo qual o maior e mantendo uma contagem dos números lidos:

```
qtd_num = int(input('Entre com a quantidade de números a serem lidos: '))
maior = float('-inf')
cont = {}
for _ in range(qtd_num):
    num = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    if num > maior:
        maior = num
    c = cont.get(num, 0)
    cont[num] = c + 1

print(f'O maior valor é {maior} e ele ocorre {cont[maior]} vezes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Estou estudando tambem, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
    i = 0
    lista = []
    qt_num = int(input("Digite a quantidade de números:\n"))
    while i < qt_num:
        lista.append(int(input("Digite um número:\n")))
        i += 1
    lista.sort()
    print(f'O maior número da lista é: {max(lista)} e ele se repete {lista.count(max(lista))}x.')
```