# Outra alternativa para não repetir essa "função" três vezes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

> Faça um Programa que leia três vetores com 10 elementos cada. Gere um quarto vetor de 30 elementos, cujos valores deverão ser compostos pelos elementos intercalados dos três outros vetores. (Usando Listas)

Eu consegui, porém gostaria de saber algum jeito para não precisar repetir o comando `for` três vezes assim como eu fiz no código abaixo:

```
n1 = list()
n2 = list()
n3 = list()
n4 = list()

for a in range(1, 11):
    n1.append(int(input(f'Digite o {a}° elemento da 1° lista: ')))
print('='*40)

for b in range(1, 11):
    n2.append(int(input(f'Digite o {b}° elemento da 2° lista: ')))
print('='*40)

for c in range(1, 11):
    n3.append(int(input(f'Digite o {c}° elemento da 3° lista: ')))
print('='*40)

for d in range(0, 10):
    n4.append(n1[d])
    n4.append(n2[d])
    n4.append(n3[d])

print(f'Intercalando as listas 1, 2 e 3 temos:\n'
      f'{n4}')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sempre que você quer generalizar um processamento que parece repetido deve pegar esse modelo e parametrizar as partes variáveis. E claro quando estou falando em parametrizar a função deve ter parâmetros. No caso a lista muda em cada um dos três e muda também o número da lista que deve ser impresso, então são esses dois parâmetros que deve criar.

```
def pegaDados(lista, ordinal):
    for n in range(1, 11):
        lista.append(int(input(f'Digite o {n}° elemento da {ordinal}° lista: ')))
    print('=' * 40)

n1 = list()
n2 = list()
n3 = list()
n4 = list()
pegaDados(n1, 1)
pegaDados(n2, 2)
pegaDados(n3, 3)

for n in range(0, 10):
    n4.append(n1[n])
    n4.append(n2[n])
    n4.append(n3[n])

print(f'Intercalando as listas 1, 2 e 3 temos:\n'
      f'{n4}')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5mioBj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Drypy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/Dry.py).

Dá para melhorar algumas coisas como capturar exceção se algo for digitado errado, o que fica mais fácil de fazer já que agora só tem um código para fazer.

E pode até fazer um laço para chamar para generalizar até a chamada das funções. Mas para isso dar certo terá que criar uma lista de listas, assim você passa cada uma das listas através de um índice da lista principal. Se acha que já consegue fazer isso pode ser um bom próximo exercício, senão deixa para depois.

Answer (score 7):

Sim, é possível e devem existir inúmeras formas de fazer isso.

Uma delas e bem simples, é criar uma função que contém a lógica onde você solicita os números ao usuário e adiciona na lista.

---

Criamos a função, `listAppend`, que vai receber a lista para adicionar os números que o usuário informar e também recebe um número em relação qual é a lista, isso é somente para imprimir 1º lista, 2º lista etc:

```
def listAppend(vector, number):
  for a in range(1, 11):
      vector.append(int(input(f'Digite o {a}° elemento da {number}° lista: ')))
  print('='*40)
```

Veja que é praticamente o mesmo código que você escreveu três vezes, mas agora isolado em uma função.

Agora que temos essa função, podemos apenas chamar ela para cada lista:

```
listAppend(n1, 1)
listAppend(n2, 2)
listAppend(n3, 3)
```

---

Seu código então ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
def listAppend(vector, number):
  for a in range(1, 11):
      vector.append(int(input(f'Digite o {a}° elemento da {number}° lista: ')))
  print('='*40)

n1 = list()
n2 = list()
n3 = list()
n4 = list()

listAppend(n1, 1)
listAppend(n2, 2)
listAppend(n3, 3)

for d in range(0, 10):
    n4.append(n1[d])
    n4.append(n2[d])
    n4.append(n3[d])

print(f'Intercalando as listas 1, 2 e 3 temos:\n'
      f'{n4}')
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/LowestWorthwhileEditor

Answer (score 1):

Eu usaria uma lista de listas, em vez das variáveis `n1`, `n2`, etc (como *provavelmente* é um exercício, e exercícios costumam ter limitações artificiais como "*não pode usar [recurso nativo útil que torna mais fácil resolver o problema]*", entendo que você talvez não queira usar isso, mas de qualquer forma deixo registrado aqui a alternativa).

```
def ler_dados_lista(indice_lista, tamanho):
    lista = []
    for n in range(tamanho):
        lista.append(int(input(f'Digite o {n + 1}° elemento da {indice_lista + 1}ª lista: ')))
    print('=' * 40)
    return lista

listas = []
for i in range(3):
    listas.append(ler_dados_lista(i, 10))

intercalados = []
for elementos in zip(*listas):
    intercalados.extend(elementos)

print(f'Intercalando as listas 1, 2 e 3 temos:\n{intercalados}')
```

A função que lê os dados de uma lista retorna esta lista, e assim eu posso adicioná-la na lista de listas usando um `for` *simples*. No final, a variável `listas` será uma lista contendo as 3 listas que foram lidas.

Depois para criar a lista com os elementos intercalados, eu uso [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), que serve para percorrer várias listas de uma vez (justamente o que você quer fazer).

O asterisco antes de `listas` serve para fazer o [*unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), ou seja, `zip(*listas)` é o mesmo que `zip(listas[0], listas[1], listas[2])`, com a diferença de ser mais sucinto e principalmente de funcionar sem eu precisar saber a quantidade de listas.

A cada iteração, a variável `elementos` será uma tupla contendo os elementos de cada uma das listas. Na primeira iteração, ela terá o primeiro elemento de cada lista, na segunda iteração, o segundo elemento e assim por diante.

Por fim, eu uso `extend` para adicionar todos os elementos de uma só vez (em vez de chamar `append` várias vezes).

Repare também que você pode criar uma lista vazia usando `[]`.

---

Para deixar mais sucinto e [*pythônico*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052), você pode trocar os *loops* acima por [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions):

```
def ler_dados_lista(indice_lista, tamanho):
    lista = [ int(input(f'Digite o {n + 1}° elemento da {indice_lista + 1}ª lista: ')) for n in range(tamanho) ]
    print('=' * 40)
    return lista

listas = [ ler_dados_lista(i, 10) for i in range(3) ]

from itertools import chain
intercalados = list(chain.from_iterable(elementos for elementos in zip(*listas)))
print(f'Intercalando as listas 1, 2 e 3 temos:\n{intercalados}')
```

Também daria para fazer assim (a diferença é que não vai imprimir um monte de `"="` entre as mensagens - se isso for desejado, então mantenha a função `ler_dados_lista`):

```
listas = [
  [ int(input(f'Digite o {n + 1}° elemento da {i + 1}ª lista: ')) for n in range(10) ]
  for i in range(3)
]
```