# Criar várias listas contendo números aleatórios

Tags: python, random

Como posso criar um código que me gere 50 listas com 12 elementos aleatórios?

Já tentei usar `while` para repetir uma função de geração de listas, mas não deu muito certo.

```
import random

def lista_random():
    lista = []

    while lista != 50:
        for i in range(0,12):
            lista.append(random.randint(1,50))
        lista.sort()
    return lista

lista = lista_random()
print(f'A sua lista é: {lista}')
```

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi. São 50 listas de listas, sendo que cada uma dessas listinhas dentro da listona deve ter 12 números aleatórios entre 1 e 50 em ordem crescente. É isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para gerar uma lista de números aleatórios, não precisa fazer um *loop* e adicionar os números um a um. O [módulo `random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) já tem duas funções prontas para isso: [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) e [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). Por exemplo, para gerar uma lista com 12 números aleatórios entre 1 e 50:

```
from random import choices, sample

tamanho = 12
valores = range(1, 51)

print(choices(valores, k=tamanho))
print(sample(valores, tamanho))
```

> ***Obs: `choices` está disponível apenas a partir do Python 3.6***

No seu código você usou `randint(1, 50)`, que gera um número aleatório entre 1 e 50. Para obter o mesmo efeito, temos que usar `range(1, 51)`, já que um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) não inclui o último número.

Ambos geram uma lista com o tamanho indicado. A diferença é que `choices` pode colocar valores repetidos na lista (o mesmo número pode aparecer mais de uma vez), enquanto `sample` garante que não haverá repetições. Escolha o que for mais adequado para o seu caso (o seu código atual permite repetições, já que cada chamada de [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) é "independente" e não há garantia de que os números gerados serão únicos na lista).

---

Para gerar 50 listas, basta criar uma lista de listas e fazer um `for` simples para acrescentar as listas:

```
from random import choices

qtd = 50
tamanho = 12
valores = range(1, 51)

listas = []
for _ in range(qtd):
    listas.append(choices(valores, k=tamanho))

print(listas)
```

Ou, usando a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052):

```
from random import choices

qtd = 50
tamanho = 12
valores = range(1, 51)

listas = [ choices(valores, k=tamanho) for _ in range(qtd) ]
print(listas)
```

---

Vi que você está ordenando as listas, então uma maneira de fazer é usar [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
listas = [ sorted(choices(valores, k=tamanho)) for _ in range(qtd) ]
```

Ou, se preferir continuar usando `sort`:

```
listas = []
for _ in range(qtd):
    lista = choices(valores, k=tamanho)
    lista.sort()
    listas.append(lista)
```

A diferença é que `sorted` retorna outra lista (ou seja, `choices` retorna uma lista, que é passada para `sorted`, que retorna outra lista), enquanto [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) ordena a lista *in place* (modifica os elementos da própria lista, sem precisar criar outra).

Answer (score 2):

É bem simples, basta você criar a lista principal (a que irá guardar as cinquenta listas) e depois criar uma sub-lista para guardar os 12 números aleatórios.

Dentro de um outro `for...range` você deve acrescentar os números aleatórios para a sub-lista. Veja abaixo como ficaria:

```
def lista_random(tamanho = 50):
    lista = []

    for i in range(tamanho):
        sub_lista = []

        for i in range(12):
            sub_lista.append(random.randint(1, 50))
        lista.append(sub_lista)

    return lista
```

Uma outra forma bem mais simples e curta, é usando *list comprehension* dessa forma:

```
lista_random = lambda tamanho: [[random.randint(1, 50) for i in range(10)] for i in range(tamanho)]
```

A ideia de criar um laço `while` não funcionou porque você não verificava se o tamanho da lista era diferente de 50 e sim se a a lista em si era diferente do número 50.

O que você deveria ter feito era utilizar a função `len()` e verificar se a quantidade de elementos da lista já tinha passado de cinquenta.

```
while len(lista) < 50:
    # Código...
```

Outro ponto em que você errou, é que você acrescentava os números à lista principal. O que você deveria ter feito como eu mostrei nos exemplos acima, é criar uma sub-lista para armazenar os números.

Answer (score 0):

Nesta questão ficou claro a **quantidade de listas**, que no caso é **50**, ficou claro também a **quantidade de elementos**, que no caso é **12**, porém, não foi mencionado o **range** do qual desejas realizar os sorteios.

Quando desejamos realizar algum sorteio, devemos deixar claro o range que utilizaremos. Para isso devemos especificar os limites **inferior** e **superior**.

Pois bem para resolvermos esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
from random import sample


def lista_random(m, n, i, f):
    lista = list()
    for c in range(1, m + 1):
        lista.append(sorted(sample(range(i, f + 1), n)))
    return lista


num = int(input('Desejas gerar quantas listas? '))
quant = int(input('Quantos números por lista? '))
ini = int(input('Limite inferior do range: '))
fin = int(input('Limite superior do range: '))

for d in lista_random(num, quant, ini, fin):
    print(d)
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/nlhwkabg-solkarped) o funcionamento do código.

Observe que quando executamos o código devemos digitar; a quantidade das listas, a quantidade de elementos de cada lista, o limite inferior do range e o limite superior do range e, em seguida, pressionar `enter`.

Tendo digitado todos esses valores, os mesmos são passados como parâmetros para a função `lista_random()`. Dentro desta função o bloco `for` controlará a confecção de todas as listas. Dentro do bloco `for` o método `sample` da biblioteca `random` sorteará **n** números, **sem repetições**, pertencentes ao **range(i, f + 1)**, em seguida, estes valores são submetidos à função `sorted()` e, consequentemente, ordenados de forma crescente e, por fim, tal lista é adicionada em `lista`.

Depois de todas estas operações o `return` da função exibirá as listas formadas.

**Observação:**

Este código é capaz de produzir e exibir `m` listas, com `n` elementos, a partir do limite inicial `i` e limite final `f` de qualquer range.

Answer (score -3):

Cheguei aqui exatamente tentando fazer um código limpo, sem condicional, sem muitos loops e funções para que eu pudesse gerar grupos de pessoas e fazer um código  para embaralhar 23 pessoas de uma lista e separá-las em grupos de 6 sendo que o último ficaria com os 5 restantes. A opção de usar choices ou sample foi uma ótima, mas está com ruido no resultado: mesmo utilizando samples, não faz com que repita quaisquer números dentro da sublista, mas  há repetição "inter-listas" e nem todos os membros são contemplados porque não fazemos uma opção .pop.

Com isso pensei que o melhor será fazer o que pensei de início:

1. gerar uma lista de 23 números;
2. gerar 4 listas vazias;
3. usar shuffle para embaralhar a lista de pessoas;
4. Tentar usar um loop com coleta de fatiamento de seis-em-seis e um condicional if para, quando não houver 6, coletar o que houver.

tks

Comment: Pietro, essa área é exclusiva para respostas à pergunta. Se possui uma nova pergunta, crie uma nova através do botão "faça uma pergunta"